# How to convert DOS/Windows newline (CRLF) to Unix newline (LF)

Tags: windows, unix, newline, carriage-return, linefeed

How can I programmatically (not using [`vi`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi)) convert DOS/Windows newlines to Unix newlines?

The `dos2unix` and `unix2dos` commands are not available on certain systems.
How can I emulate them with commands such as `sed`, `awk`, and `tr`?

Comment: In general, just install `dos2unix` using your package manager, it really is much simpler and does exist on most platforms.

Comment: Agreed! @BradKoch Simple as 'brew install dos2unix' on Mac OSX

Comment: Not all users have root access, and thus cannot install packages. Maybe that's why the user asked the very specific question he asked.

Comment: Related: [Why does my tool output overwrite itself and how do I fix it?](/q/45772525/4518341)

Answer (score 427):

You can use `tr` to convert from DOS to Unix; however, you can only do this safely if CR appears in your file only as the first byte of a CRLF byte pair.  This is usually the case.  You then use:

```
tr -d '\015' <DOS-file >UNIX-file
```

Note that the name `DOS-file` is different from the name `UNIX-file`; if you try to use the same name twice, you will end up with no data in the file.

You can't do it the other way round (with standard 'tr').

If you know how to enter carriage return into a script (<kbd>control-V</kbd>, <kbd>control-M</kbd> to enter control-M), then:

```
sed 's/^M$//'     # DOS to Unix
sed 's/$/^M/'     # Unix to DOS
```

where the '^M' is the control-M character.  You can also use the `bash` [ANSI-C Quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) mechanism to specify the carriage return:

```
sed $'s/\r$//'     # DOS to Unix
sed $'s/$/\r/'     # Unix to DOS
```

However, if you're going to have to do this very often (more than once, roughly speaking), it is far more sensible to install the conversion programs (e.g. [`dos2unix`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dos2unix) and [`unix2dos`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/unix2dos), or perhaps [`dtou`](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/utils/utils_4.html) and [`utod`](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/utils/utils_5.html)) and use them.

If you need to process entire directories and subdirectories, you can use `zip`:

```
zip -r -ll zipfile.zip somedir/
unzip zipfile.zip
```

This will create a zip archive with line endings changed from CRLF to CR. `unzip` will then put the converted files back in place (and ask you file by file - you can answer: Yes-to-all). Credits to @vmsnomad for pointing this out.

Comment: using `tr -d '\015' <DOS-file >UNIX-file` where `DOS-file` == `UNIX-file` just results in an empty file. The output file has to be a different file, unfortunately.

Comment: @ButtleButkus: Well, yes; that's why I used two different names.  If you zap the input file before the program reads it all, as you do when you use the same name twice, you end up with an empty file. That is uniform behaviour on Unix-like systems. It requires special code to handle overwriting an input file safely. Follow the instructions and you will be OK.

Comment: I seem to remember in-file search-replace functionality somehwere.

Comment: There are places; you have to know where to find them. Within limits, the GNU `sed` option `-i` (for in-place) works; the limits are linked files and symlinks. The `sort` command has 'always' (since 1979, if not earlier) supported the `-o` option which can list one of the input files.  However, that is in part because `sort` must read all its input before it can write any of its output. Other programs sporadically support overwriting one of their input files.  You can find a general purpose program (script) to avoid problems in _'The UNIX Programming Environment'_ by Kernighan & Pike.

Comment: The third option worked for me, thanks.  I did use the -i option:  `sed -i $'s/\r$//' filename` - to edit in place.  I am working on a machine that does not have access to the internet, so software installation is a problem.

Comment: Here's how to do it without changing the filename: `tr -d '\015' < original_file > t && mv t original_file` - basically works by creating temp file, then overwriting the old one with it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler fyi, for macOS users: `sed` does not (by default, not sure you can change this?) recognise the escaped versions `\r`, `\015`, `\x0d` for carriage return; `sed` does recognise CR when entered with `ctrl-v ctrl-m` as described above (), which is ok for the command line; for scripts try `sed "s/$(printf '\r')$//"` (hat tip @twm), or fallback to `tr`, which recognises `\r` and `\015`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The general-purpose program is called `sponge` and can be found in [moreutils](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/): `tr -d '\015' < original_file | sponge original_file`. I use it daily.

Comment: How do I do this recursively?

Comment: @AaronFranke: it depends on what your scenario looks like.  In my book, if you need to modify a whole lot of files the same way, you use a script to encapsulate the processing (even if you throw it away after you've finished), and then use a tool such as `find` to identify the files that need changing (or otherwise create a list of file names — one hopes they don't have spaces and other unruly punctuation in the names) and then apply the script to the files.  Using `find … -exec sh script.sh {} +` is pretty effective.  The alternatives are legion.  The `find` technique works with absurd names.

Comment: if you accidantly apply `sed $'s/$/\r/'` twice it will have the CR twice. For scripting solutions I recommend the following: `sed 's/^$/\r/;s/\([^\r]\)$/\1\r/g'`
For simplicity I would state this as the third way to make the original idea point out.

Comment: The zip file method works really well!

Comment: I used the `zip` method, works really fine. But one thing that can be good to know is that `zip` preserves timestamps as default. Sometimes that's good, but if you want new timestamps use `-DD` for folders and files, `-D` is only folders. On VMS it's sets timestamps for folders by default, and `-D` is folders and files.

Answer (score 102):

You can use Vim programmatically with the option `-c {command}`:

DOS to Unix:

```
vim file.txt -c "set ff=unix" -c ":wq"
```

Unix to DOS:

```
vim file.txt -c "set ff=dos" -c ":wq"
```

`"set ff=unix/dos"` means change fileformat (ff) of the file to Unix/DOS end of line format.

`":wq"` means write the file to disk and quit the editor (allowing to use the command in a loop).

Comment: you can use ":x" instead of ":wq"

Answer (score 86):

Use:

```
tr -d "\r" < file
```

Take a look [here](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt) for examples using `sed`:

```
# In a Unix environment: convert DOS newlines (CR/LF) to Unix format.
sed 's/.$//'               # Assumes that all lines end with CR/LF
sed 's/^M$//'              # In Bash/tcsh, press Ctrl-V then Ctrl-M
sed 's/\x0D$//'            # Works on ssed, gsed 3.02.80 or higher

# In a Unix environment: convert Unix newlines (LF) to DOS format.
sed "s/$/`echo -e \\\r`/"            # Command line under ksh
sed 's/$'"/`echo \\\r`/"             # Command line under bash
sed "s/$/`echo \\\r`/"               # Command line under zsh
sed 's/$/\r/'                        # gsed 3.02.80 or higher
```

Use [`sed -i`](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Invoking-sed.html) for in-place conversion, e.g., `sed -i 's/..../' file`.

Comment: I used a variant since my file only had `\r` : `tr "\r" "\n" < infile > outfile`

Comment: @MattTodd could you post this as an answer? the `-d` is featured more frequently and will not help in the "only `\r`" situation.

Comment: Note that the proposed `\r` to `\n` mapping has the effect of double-spacing the files; each single CRLF line ending in DOS becomes `\n\n` in Unix.

Comment: Can I do this recursively?

Answer (score 59):

Install [`dos2unix`](https://waterlan.home.xs4all.nl/dos2unix.html), then convert a file in-place with

```
dos2unix <filename>
```

To output converted text to a different file use

```
dos2unix -n <input-file> <output-file>
```

---

You can install it on Ubuntu or Debian with

```
sudo apt install dos2unix
```

or on macOS using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/)

```
brew install dos2unix
```

Comment: I know the question asks for alternatives to dos2unix but it's the first google result.

Answer (score 34):

Using AWK you can do:

```
awk '{ sub("\r$", ""); print }' dos.txt > unix.txt
```

Using Perl you can do:

```
perl -pe 's/\r$//' < dos.txt > unix.txt
```

Comment: A nice, _portable_ `awk` solution.

Answer (score 19):

This problem can be solved with standard tools, but there are sufficiently many traps for the unwary that I recommend you install the [`flip`](http://linux.maruhn.com/sec/flip.html) command, which was written over 20 years ago by Rahul Dhesi, the author of `zoo`.
It does an excellent job converting file formats while, for example, avoiding the inadvertant destruction of binary files, which is a little too easy if you just race around altering every CRLF you see...

Comment: Any way to do this in a streaming fashion, without modifying the original file?

Comment: @augurar you may check "similar packages" https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/flip

Comment: I had an experience of breaking half of my OS just by running texxto with a wrong flag. Be careful especially if you want to do it on entire folders.

Comment: The link seems to be broken (times out - *"504 Gateway Time-out"*).

Answer (score 16):

If you don't have access to **dos2unix**, but can read this page, then you can copy/paste **dos2unix.py** from here.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""\
convert dos linefeeds (crlf) to unix (lf)
usage: dos2unix.py <input> <output>
"""
import sys

if len(sys.argv[1:]) != 2:
  sys.exit(__doc__)

content = ''
outsize = 0
with open(sys.argv[1], 'rb') as infile:
  content = infile.read()
with open(sys.argv[2], 'wb') as output:
  for line in content.splitlines():
    outsize += len(line) + 1
    output.write(line + '\n')

print("Done. Saved %s bytes." % (len(content)-outsize))
```

<sub>(Cross-posted [from Super User](https://superuser.com/a/667743/140301).)</sub>

Comment: The usage is misleading. The real `dos2unix` converts *all* input files by default. Your usage implies `-n` parameter. And the real `dos2unix` is a filter that reads from stdin, writes to stdout if the files are not given.

Comment: Also, this won't work on some platforms since there is no `python` -- they apparently can't be bothered with backward compatibility, so it is `python2` or `python3` or ...

Answer (score 15):

The solutions posted so far only deal with part of the problem, converting DOS/Windows' CRLF into Unix's LF; the part they're missing is that DOS use CRLF as a line *separator*, while Unix uses LF as a line *terminator*.  The difference is that a DOS file (usually) won't have anything after the last line in the file, while Unix will.  To do the conversion properly, you need to add that final LF (unless the file is zero-length, i.e. has no lines in it at all).  My favorite incantation for this (with a little added logic to handle Mac-style CR-separated files, and not molest files that're already in unix format) is a bit of perl:

```
perl -pe 'if ( s/\r\n?/\n/g ) { $f=1 }; if ( $f || ! $m ) { s/([^\n])\z/$1\n/ }; $m=1' PCfile.txt
```

Note that this sends the Unixified version of the file to stdout.  If you want to replace the file with a Unixified version, add perl's `-i` flag.

Comment: @LudovicZenohateLagouardette Was it a plain text file (i.e. csv or tab-demited text), or something else? If it was in some database-ish format, manipulating it as if it was text is very likely to corrupt its internal structure.

Comment: A plain text csv, but I think the enconding was strange. I think it messed up because of that. However don't worry. I am always collecting backups an this wasn't even the real dataset,  just a 1gb one. The real is a 26gb.

Answer (score 10):

It is super duper easy with [PCRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions);

As a script, or replace `$@` with your files.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
perl -pi -e 's/\r\n/\n/g' -- $@
```

> This will overwrite your files in place!
>
> I recommend only doing this with a backup (version control or otherwise)

Comment: Thank you! This works, although I'm writing the filename and no `--`.
I chose this solution because it's easy to understand and adapt for me.
FYI, this is what the switches do:
`-p` assume a "while input" loop, `-i` edit input file in place, `-e` execute following command

Comment: Strictly speaking, PCRE is a reimplementation of Perl's regex engine, not the regex engine from Perl. They both have this capability, though there are also differences, in spite of the impication in the name.

Answer (score 6):

I had just to ponder that same question (on Windows-side, but equally applicable to Linux).

Surprisingly, nobody mentioned a very much automated way of doing CRLF <-> LF conversion for text-files using the good old `zip -ll` option (Info-ZIP):

```
zip -ll textfiles-lf.zip files-with-crlf-eol.*
unzip textfiles-lf.zip
```

NOTE: this would create a ZIP file preserving the original file names, but converting the line endings to LF. Then `unzip` would extract the files as zip'ed, that is, with their original names (but with LF-endings), thus prompting to overwrite the local original files if any.

The relevant excerpt from the `zip --help`:

```
zip --help
...
-l   convert LF to CR LF (-ll CR LF to LF)
```

Comment: Best answer, according to me, as it can process entire directories and sub-directories. I'm glad I digged that far down.

Comment: This works really good! But one thing that can be good to remember is that `zip` preserves timestamps as default. Sometimes that's good, but if you want new timestamps use `-DD` for folders and files, `-D` is only folders. On VMS it's sets timestamps for folders by default, and `-D` is folders and files.

Answer (score 6):

Interestingly, in my [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway) on Windows, `sed ""` did the trick already:

```
$ echo -e "abc\r" >tst.txt
$ file tst.txt
tst.txt: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
$ sed -i "" tst.txt
$ file tst.txt
tst.txt: ASCII text
```

My guess is that [sed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) ignores them when reading lines from the input and always writes Unix line endings to the output.

Comment: On a LF type system like GNU/Linux, `sed ""` will not do the trick, though.

Answer (score 5):

An even simpler [AWK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) solution without a program:

```
awk -v ORS='\r\n' '1' unix.txt > dos.txt
```

*Technically '1' is your program, because AWK requires one when the given option.*

Alternatively, an internal solution is:

```
while IFS= read -r line;
do printf '%s\n' "${line%$'\r'}";
done < dos.txt > unix.txt
```

Comment: That's handy, but just to be clear: this translates Unix -> Windows/DOS, which is the _opposite direction_ of what the OP asked for.

Comment: It was done on purpose, left as an exercise for the author.  _eyerolls_
`awk -v RS='\r\n' '1' dos.txt > unix.txt`

Comment: Great (and kudos to you for pedagogic finesse).

Comment: "b/c awk requires one when given option." - awk _always_ requires a program, whether options are specified or not.

Comment: The pure bash solution is interesting, but much slower than an equivalent `awk` or `sed` solution. Also, you must use `while IFS= read -r line` to faithfully preserve the input lines, otherwise leading and trailing whitespace is trimmed (alternatively, use no variable name in the `read` command and work with `$REPLY`).

Comment: Why clear $IFS?  If you read in to one variable (or none, and implicitly `$READ`), read just splits on line endings, and you can just use echo instead of printf (echo is more likely to be a builtin, and it's generally faster).  So, using ctrl-v+ctrl-m to type the \r, one can simply do `while read -r; do echo "${REPLY%^M}"; done < file > file.fixed` and it's about the same speed as sed.

Answer (score 4):

For Mac OS X if you have [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_(package_manager)) installed ([http://brew.sh/](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_(package_manager))):

```
brew install dos2unix

for csv in *.csv; do dos2unix -c mac ${csv}; done;
```

Make sure you have made copies of the files, as this command will modify the files in place.
The `-c mac` option makes the switch to be compatible with OS X.

Comment: This answer really doesn't the original poster's question.

Comment: OS X users should not use `-c mac`, which is for converting pre-OS X `CR`-only newlines. You want to use that mode only for files to and from Mac OS 9 or before.

Answer (score 4):

```
sed -i.bak --expression='s/\r\n/\n/g' <file_path>
```

Since the question mentions sed, this is the most straightforward way to use sed to achieve this. The expression says replace all carriage-returns and line-feeds with just line-feeds only. That is what you need when you go from Windows to Unix. I verified it works.

Comment: Hey John Paul--this answer got flagged for deletion so came up in a review queue for me.  In general, when you've got a question like this that's 8 years old, with 22 answers, you'll want to explain how your answer is useful in a way that other existing answers are not.

Comment: I could not get this to work when adding `--in-place mydosfile.txt` to the end (or piping to a file). The end result was the file still had CRLF. I was testing on a Graviton (AArch64) EC2 instance.

Comment: @NeilC.Obremski   I updated with full command line, please try that. It will also make a backup before change.

Comment: `sed 's/\r\n/\n/g'` does not match anything. Refer to [can-sed-replace-new-line-characters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114943/can-sed-replace-new-line-characters)

Comment: It worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Just complementing @Jonathan Leffler's excellent answer, **if you have a file with mixed line endings (LF and CRLF) and you need to normalize to CRLF (DOS)**, use the following commands in sequence...

```
# DOS to Unix
sed -i $'s/\r$//' "<YOUR_FILE>"

# Unix to DOS (normalized)
sed -i $'s/$/\r/' "<YOUR_FILE>"
```

**NOTE:** If you have a file with mixed line endings (LF and CRLF), the second command above alone will cause a mess.

If you need to convert to LF (Unix) the first command alone will be enough...

```
# DOS to Unix
sed -i $'s/\r$//' "<YOUR_FILE>"
```

**Thanks!**

**[Ref(s).:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/3777853/3223785 **]**

Answer (score 3):

[TIMTOWTDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it)!

```
perl -pe 's/\r\n/\n/; s/([^\n])\z/$1\n/ if eof' PCfile.txt
```

Based on [Gordon Davisson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613800/how-to-convert-dos-windows-newline-crlf-to-unix-newline-lf-in-a-bash-script/2614296#2614296).

One must consider the possibility of `[noeol]`...

Answer (score 3):

You can use [AWK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK). Set the record separator (`RS`) to a regular expression that matches all possible newline character, or characters. And set the output record separator (`ORS`) to the Unix-style newline character.

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\r|\n|\r\n|\n\r";ORS="\n"}{print}' windows_or_macos.txt > unix.txt
```

Comment: That's the one that worked for me (MacOS, `git diff` shows ^M, edited in vim)

Comment: Your command put an extra blank line in between every line when converting a DOS file. Doing this `awk 'BEGIN{RS="\r\n";ORS=""}{print}' dosfile > unixfile`  fixed that issue, but it still does not fix the missing EOL on the last line.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
tr "\r" "\n" < sampledata.csv > sampledata2.csv
```

Comment: This will convert every _single_ DOS-newline into _two_ UNIX-newlines.

Answer (score 2):

On Linux, it's easy to convert ^M (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>) to *nix newlines (^J) with sed.

It will be something like this on the CLI, and there will actually be a line break in the text. However, the `\` passes that `^J` along to sed:

```
sed 's/^M/\
/g' < ffmpeg.log > new.log
```

You get this by using ^V (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>), ^M (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>) and `\` (backslash) as you type:

```
sed 's/^V^M/\^V^J/g' < ffmpeg.log > new.log
```

Answer (score 0):

As an extension to [Jonathan Leffler's Unix to DOS solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613800/how-to-convert-dos-windows-newline-crlf-to-unix-newline-lf-in-a-bash-script/2613834#2613834), to safely convert to DOS when you're unsure of the file's current line endings:

```
sed '/^M$/! s/$/^M/'
```

This checks that the line does not already end in CRLF before converting to CRLF.

Answer (score 0):

I made a script based on the accepted answer, so you can convert it directly without needing an additional file in the end and removing and renaming afterwards.

```
convert-crlf-to-lf() {
    file="$1"
    tr -d '\015' <"$file" >"$file"2
    rm -rf "$file"
    mv "$file"2 "$file"
}
```

Just make sure if you have a file like "file1.txt" that "file1.txt2" doesn't already exist or it will be overwritten. I use this as a temporary place to store the file in.

Answer (score 0):

With Bash 4.2 and newer you can use something like this to strip the trailing CR, which only uses Bash built-ins:

```
if [[ "${str: -1}" == $'\r' ]]; then
    str="${str:: -1}"
fi
```

Answer (score -3):

I tried

```
sed 's/^M$//' file.txt
```

on [OS X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X) as well as several other methods (*[Fixing Dos Line Endings](http://www.thingy-ma-jig.co.uk/blog/25-11-2010/fixing-dos-line-endings)* or http://hintsforums.macworld.com/archive/index.php/t-125.html). None worked, and the file remained unchanged (by the way, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> was needed to reproduce `^M`). In the end I used [TextWrangler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBEdit#TextWrangler). It's not strictly command line, but it works and it doesn't complain.

Comment: The hintsforums.macworld.com link is (effectively) broken - it redirects to the main page, "http://hints.macworld.com/"

Comment: command is missing the -i option