# How do I convert LF to CRLF?

Tags: python, unix

I found a list of the majority of English words online, but the line breaks are of unix-style (encoded in Unicode: UTF-8). I found it on this website: http://dreamsteep.com/projects/the-english-open-word-list.html

How do I convert the line breaks to CRLF so I can iterate over them? The program I will be using them in goes through each line in the file, so the words have to be one per line.

This is a portion of the file: `bitbackbitebackbiterbackbitersbackbitesbackbitingbackbittenbackboard`

It should be:

```
bit
backbite
backbiter
backbiters
backbites
backbiting
backbitten
backboard
```

How can I convert my files to this type? Note: it's 26 files (one per letter) with 80,000 words or so in total (so the program should be very fast).

I don't know where to start because I've never worked with unicode. Thanks in advance!

Using `rU` as the parameter (as suggested), with this in my code:

```
with open(my_file_name, 'rU') as my_file:
    for line in my_file:
        new_words.append(str(line))
my_file.close()
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    addWords('B Words')
  File "D:\my_stuff\Google Drive\documents\SCHOOL\Programming\Python\Programming Class\hangman.py", line 138, in addWords
    for line in my_file:
  File "C:\Python3.3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 7488: character maps to <undefined>
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: you could possibly find this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891076/how-to-convert-windows-end-of-line-in-unix-end-of-line-cr-lf-to-lf helpful

Comment: Can't you make your program able to handle both types of line ending?

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin I already have a file with a list of words. In addition, I've never used unicode (as stated) so I don't know how to handle those types of endings.

Comment: In unix use the sed command

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Instead of converting, you should be able to just open the file using Python's [universal newline support](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-universal-newlines):

```
f = open('words.txt', 'rU')
```

(Note the `U`.)

Comment: it seems this is deprecated now : https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#open

Answer (score 16):

You can use the replace method of strings. Like

```
txt.replace('\n', '\r\n')
```

EDIT :
in your case :

```
with open('input.txt') as inp, open('output.txt', 'w') as out:
    txt = inp.read()
    txt = txt.replace('\n', '\r\n')
    out.write(txt)
```

Comment: If you want to change all the line endings in the same file without creating a new output file, look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43678795/3459910

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to convert the line endings in the files in order to be able to iterate over them. As suggested by NPE, simply use [python's universal newlines mode](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open).

The UnicodeDecodeError happens because the files you are processing are encoded as UTF-8 and when you attempt to decode the contents from bytes to a string, via `str(line)`, Python is using the `cp1252` encoding to convert the bytes read from the file into a Python 3 string (i.e. a sequence of unicode code points). However, there are bytes in those files that cannot be decoded with the `cp1252` encoding and that causes a UnicodeDecodeError.

If you change `str(line)` to `line.decode('utf-8')` you should no longer get the UnicodeDecodeError. Check out the [Text Vs. Data Instead of Unicode Vs. 8-bit](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#text-vs-data-instead-of-unicode-vs-8-bit) writeup for some more details.

Finally, you might also find [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use cereja package

```
pip install cereja==1.2.0
```

```
import cereja
cereja.lf_to_crlf(dir_or_file_path)
```

or

`cereja.lf_to_crlf(dir_or_file_path, ext_in=[“.py”,”.csv”])`

You can substitute for any standard.  See the filetools module

Answer (score 0):

**Year 2023:**

It is very old question with very old answers for `Python 2`
but it seems option `U` in `open()` is deprecated (or even removed) in `Python 3`.

In `Python 3` you can use `newline="\r\n"` in `open()` to write with `\r\n`
(and it doesn't need `replace()`)

```
with open('input.txt') as file_in:
    txt = file_in.read()

with open('output.txt', 'w', newline='\r\n') as file_out:
    file_out.write(txt)
```

---

But error in question shows also problem with `cp1252.py`
and it means it tried to read it as `cp1252`, not `utf-8`.

In `Python 3` it may need to use `encoding="utf-8"` in `open()`

```
with open('input.txt', encoding="utf-8") as file_in:
    txt = file_in.read()
```

Doc: [open()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)

---

You may also use `bytes-mode` instead of `text-mode`in open (`rb`, `wb`)
and it will need `replace()` with bytes `b"\r"` and `b"\r\n"`

```
with open('input.txt', 'rb') as file_in:
    bytes_data = file_in.read()

bytes_data = bytes_data.replace(b'\n', b'\r\n')

with open('output.txt', 'wb') as file_out:
    file_out.write(bytes_data)
```

It doesn't care if file uses `utf-8` or `cp1252`
but I don't know if some chars in `utf-8` or `cp1252` doesn't use `\n` as part of char code and it may create mistakes in text.