# python 2: open and parse text file with mixed newline characters

Tags: python

Using Python 2.7 (Anaconda Distribution): I need to parse a text file randomly terminating lines on either `"\n"` or `"\r\n"`. When I use the `open` function with the option `"rb"` the script successfully interprets `"\n"` as a line terminator, but not `"\r\n"`. When I use `open` with option `"rU"` (supposedly offers universal newlines support), the script breaks lines at `"\r\n"` but not  at `"\n"`. How can I open the file recognizing either of these different line terminators?

```
# recognizes "\n" but not "\r\n"
with open(infile, 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='|')

# recognizes "\r\n" but not "\n"
with open(infile, 'rU') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='|')
```

Comment: What about using `open(infile, 'rbU')`?

Comment: @Hook 'rbU' gives the same result as 'rU'.

Comment: Friendly side-note that Python 2.7 reached end of life 1 Jan 2020; you could consider moving to 3.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert CRLF to LF on a Windows machine in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36422107/how-to-convert-crlf-to-lf-on-a-windows-machine-in-python) (There's a simple way to do it in-line.)

Answer (score 3):

Is it an option to simply sanitize your input files before feeding them to the python script? `dos2unix` will do convert your mixed-case `\r\n` and `\n` endings to just `\n` ones for you.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this, and now it doesn't matter whether I use 'rb' or 'rU', I can't parse `\n` line terminators. After additional diagnostics, it looks like the issue is caused by a field containing a single, unclosed double-quotation mark ("). Good tool to know about though.

Comment: Oof, yeah, stuff like that is a pain. Does stuff work ok now if you take the " out?

Comment: After a crash course in sed to remove those characters, it worked. Thanks.