# Ubuntu Python shebang line not working

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, python-2.7, ubuntu-12.04

Unable to get shebang line working in Ubuntu for python script. I only get a command not found error each time.

test.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

print ('!')
```

Ran

```
:which python
/usr/bin/python
```

Played around with different locations for python in the shebang but no luck including what was provided by which python. Any tips on how to troubleshoot this?

Thanks

Comment: Make sure your line endings are unix `\n` newlines.

Comment: I made the test file in nano. I usually use sublime but this is on my server so just whipped it up in nano. I honestly have no idea how to view special chars in nano. I just assumed since I made it on linux it would handle the new line appropriately.

Comment: It probably is unix newlines then; is the file executable? (`chmod +x scriptname.py`)

Comment: it is indeed. Not sure if this helps but if I run (/usr/bin/python test.py) it runs like a champ

Comment: What does `file test.py` say?

Comment: If you're using UTF-8, copied from Windows, remember to remove BOM as well

Comment: Try running `dos2unix <myscript>` to fix the line endings and then try you script again.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you are trying to run the command as

```
$ test.py
```

the error may not have anything to do with the shebang. Rather, the directory that test.py resides in is not in your `PATH`. Try

```
$ ./test.py
```

to bypass `PATH` lookup.

(This is in addition to making sure that the script itself is executable.)

Comment: ugh that was my primary problem in testing, can you explain how the logic of ./test.py works?

Comment: When your command consists of a single word, the shell looks for that command in each directory stored in `PATH`, starting with the first, and using the first match it finds. The current directory (.) is typically not in `PATH`, as it could be a security risk, so you need to specify the exact path as `./test.py` (the file `test.py` in the current directory).

Comment: Not to keep asking but why is PATH a security risk?

Comment: @DrewK: adding the current directory to PATH is considered a security risk because an attacker would be able to "override" standard commands by placing a script in the current directory. Imagine a custom `ls` script which acts exactly as normal `ls` except not showing directories called `.evil-hidden-stuff`...

Comment: I've never seen it stated this way, but I think the recommendation against putting '.' in your `PATH` would extend to any relative path. The idea is that the lookups should conform to a fixed set of directories that does not depend on your current working directory.

Answer (score 9):

On the python [docs page](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6/using/unix.html) it says:

> To easily use Python scripts on Unix, you need to make them
>   executable, e.g. with
>
> $ chmod +x script and put an appropriate Shebang line at the top of
>   the script. A good choice is usually
>
> #!/usr/bin/env python
>   which searches for the Python interpreter in the whole PATH. However,
>   some Unices may not have the env command, so you may need to hardcode
>   /usr/bin/python as the interpreter path.

I don't know if this applies for you or not.

Comment: I thought that my apply and I had tried use those paths and could not get it to run.

Answer (score 6):

Apart from executing the script with a preceding dot or making it executable, there might be another issue:

If you try to use a script written with a windows editor, it may contain windows line endings. Removing these can make the shebang work again.

To remove such line endings, refer to [How to convert Windows end of line in Unix end of line (CR/LF to LF)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891076/how-to-convert-windows-end-of-line-in-unix-end-of-line-cr-lf-to-lf) for instance.

See also my general remarks on failed shebang evaluations [at my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30128006/1150303).

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the "**FIRST LINE**" is the shebang.
Do not give any newline character in the beginning of the file.
"**No newline character in beginning**"

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to a kernel misconfiguration. [Take a look at your kernel's config](https://superuser.com/a/287372/278221) options, and check if [`CONFIG_BINFMT_SCRIPT`](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/BINFMT_SCRIPT.html) is set:

```
zcat /proc/config.gz | grep CONFIG_BINFMT_SCRIPT
```

If the output of this command is **anything besides** `CONFIG_BINFMT_SCRIPT=y`, this means that your kernel will not allow you to use shebangs. You will need to get a new kernel or recompile your current kernel with `CONFIG_BINFMT_SCRIPT=y`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check your line ending in gitbash/pycharm terminal by typing,

cat .gitattributes

this will list the setup, for linux setup paste this
*.sh text eol=lf

if this doesnt work, then better create a new branch and delete the exisiting file and create newfile.

This worked for me