# Setting default interpreter for a python script is not working

Tags: python, linux, interpreter

Here is my environment

```
> lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: Scientific
Description:    Scientific Linux release 6.8 (Carbon)
Release:        6.8
Codename:       Carbon

> /home/ktew/python/bin/python --version
Python 2.7.18
```

I have added the following line as the first line in my python script.

```
#!/home/ktew/python/bin/python
```

The python script is executable.

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 ktew ktew   12753 Sep 23 10:35 compare_trims_by_version_5.py*
```

This line of command is working well.

```
/home/ktew/python/bin/python compare_trims_by_version_5.py
```

However, Command not found when I run it.

```
> ./compare_trims_by_version_5.py
./compare_trims_by_version_5.py: Command not found.
```

Comment: Could it be an imported module that is not resolving? Try emptying out the script (except your shebang) and put just a print statement and see if it works

Comment: I have tried it out but the error remains the same. I even changed the shebang to #!/usr/bin/python (default python)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/30127747/5057185. I have written the script with windows editor and it contains windows line endings(CR/LF). I used the `dos2unix` command to fix line endings.

To summarize:

1. Add the shebang at the first line of script. `#!/home/ktew/python/bin/python`
2. Make sure the script is executable. `chmod +x script`
3. Use `./script.py` instead of `script.py` in case your directory is not in your PATH
4. Ensure the line ending is correct (LF instead of CR/LF). Use `dos2unix` to fix it.

Answer (score -1):

The error message looks like the system is trying to run as a shell script instead of using the Python interpreter (ref: [Python error: command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30285154/python-error-command-not-found)). In this case, nothing seems to be out of place with your Python interpreter. The referred stackoverflow page suggests using `#!/usr/bin/env python`, recommend you try that as well.

Comment: I have tried it out by changing the shebang to #!/usr/bin/python (default python) but the error remains the same.