# Shebang doesn't work with python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, shebang

I have the following program:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

print("Hello")
```

Via terminal I do `test.py` and I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/site.py", line 629, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/site.py", line 614, in main
    known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/site.py", line 284, in addusersitepackages
    user_site = getusersitepackages()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/site.py", line 260, in getusersitepackages
    user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/site.py", line 250, in getuserbase
    USER_BASE = get_config_var('userbase')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/sysconfig.py", line 610, in get_config_var
    return get_config_vars().get(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/sysconfig.py", line 560, in get_config_vars
    _init_posix(_CONFIG_VARS)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/sysconfig.py", line 432, in _init_posix
    from _sysconfigdata import build_time_vars
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/_sysconfigdata.py", line 6, in <module>
    from _sysconfigdata_m import *
ImportError: No module named '_sysconfigdata_m'
```

Instead if I type `python3 test.py` it works, I get:

`Hello`

P.S. `which python3` ----> `/usr/local/bin/python3`

Comment: Try `#!/usr/bin/env python3`.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/limetext/lime/issues/155 If that doesn't help, see https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=ImportError%3A+No+module+named+%27_sysconfigdata_m%27

Comment: @TomLeese I still get errors

Comment: Duplicate [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22169908/raspberry-pi-python-shebang-with-cgi-server#comment33650028_22169908)

Comment: @VivienG: that doesn't look like the same issue at all.

Comment: After more research I found [that](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2013-September/097760.html) I think this thread can be usefull for him.

Comment: If [hello world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22Hello,_World!%22_program) doesn't work, then you have a bad installation or environment. That's the whole reason "hello world" exists.

Comment: It doesn't apply to OP, but beware : if running your script with `python myscript.py`, the shebang will be ignored, obviously (well, unless you're distracted like me…).  Use `python3 myscript.py`, of course.

Answer (score 90):

Generally, take care of some pitfalls:

1. set the **executable flag** on the script: `chmod u+x test.py`
2. try to **execute with a preceding dot** "./", so call `./test.py` otherwise it might execute some other script from within your `PATH`
3. also make sure **you don't have windows line endings**, this seems to prevent the shebang evaluation, too. There are some suggestions around, e.g. [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11680914/1150303), on how to convert the format.

   If `python3 test.py` works, then the windows line endings are probably your problem.
4. **`#!/usr/bin/env python3`** is the best way to define the shebang (i.e. use this as first line of your script), since the python binary may be installed somewhere else. `env` will inspect the `PATH` environment to find the binary
5. As @ShaileshKumarMPatel has pointed out in the comments here, make sure, there's no wrong line beginnings (color characters etc)

EDIT: The OP's kind of error looks like windows line endings to me. I've had them, too, with different output though

Comment: Windows line ending was my problem too

Comment: The executable flag was the problem in my case. Thanks!

Comment: Changing the shebang to `#!/usr/bin/env python3` worked for me.

Comment: Not only line ending can be problem, sometimes "line beginning" can also be problem. I found out problem once in my script. There can be unreadable character at the beginning of line. This can be inferred from wrong color of line in pico/nano/geany editors. Eighter deleting and rewritng line or pressing delete at start of line(which appearantly donot delete anything, but deletes un-seen character) solved the problem

Answer (score 5):

If the python script has come into contact with a windows machine it is worth trying to clean up the line endings with:

```
$ dos2unix programmer.py
```

Answer (score 2):

Windows end line was my problem too. Writing the same program with a linux editor like VI solved it for me. Also, using "less" command , i was able to see the windows end line characters

Answer (score 1):

You might see `ImportError: No module named '_sysconfigdata_m'` because `/usr/lib/command-not-found` is broken on your system due to [the ubuntu bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python3.3/+bug/1192890).

To workaround it, run `./test.py`, not `test.py` -- the current directory is not in `$PATH` usually (due to security reasons) and therefore you should specify the path explicitly otherwise the command is not found that may lead to trying to run `/usr/lib/command-not-found` that results in the `ImportError`.

If `./test.py` fails with the same error then check that there is no [`'\r\v\f'` (unexpected whitespace) in the shebang](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/454074/23044) (`print(repr(open('test.py', 'rb').readline()))`). If `test.py` uses Windows newlines then the attempt to find `'/usr/local/bin/python3\r'` (notice: `'\r'` due to `'\r\n'` newline) is likely to fail that may trigger the error.

Answer (score 1):

Another reason can be the presence of the [byte order mark (BOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the start of the file, if the file is using an Unicode encoding.

The presence of the BOM was my problem for my Python script encoded in UTF-8. I removed the BOM using my text editor Geany, but Notepad++ can also remove it, and I was able to run my script with a starting shebang line with ./myscript.py .

To quote Wikipedia :

> The Unicode Standard permits the BOM in UTF-8, but does not require
> or recommend its use. Byte order has no meaning in UTF-8 [...]

Comment: Thanks, Can you describe more?? please try to edit your post and say you remove what?  `I removed it and it worked.`