# Continuation in gfortran 5.2.0

Tags: fortran, fortran90, gfortran

I need to work on Fortran90 code on my Macbook Pro, which was written on Microsoft Developer Tools years ago. As a free option, I have installed `gfortran` on my Macbook to be able to compile it. The original code includes `&` continuation character for the long lines but I am not able to use it. Without `&` character, everything works fine. What might be the problem? Do I need to activate something to be able to use `&` character?

For example, I think something like this should work:

```
x = 1 
y = 2 
z = x+ 
&y 
end
```

But instead, I am having this error. It might be end of line error. How can I solve it?

```
3:72: Error: Syntax error in expression at (1) 
4:9: Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
```

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: You need to show the code, the `&` works in gfortran just fine if used properly. Also report the file name and the command you use and the errors you see.

Comment: More likely the end-of-line characters windows vs. unix cause your trouble. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/q/3891076/577108.

Comment: Alright, for example, something like that should work in Fortran as long as I know:
<code>
   x = 1
   y = 2
   z = x+
   &y
<code>
But instead, I am having this error. It might be end of line error. How can I solve it?

3:72: Error: Syntax error in expression at (1)
4:9: Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
Error: Unexpected end of file

Comment: @AlexanderVogt Thank you for your help. I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In free-form Fortran, the line continuation character (`&`) at the end of the line to be continued. Your code should read:

```
program test
  x = 1 
  y = 2 
  z = x+ &
  y 
end program
```

This is stated in the Fortran Standard (here: 2008, but applicable as well for Fortran 90), Cl. 3.3.2.4 "Free form statement continuation":

> 1     The character “&” is used to indicate that the statement is continued on the next line that is not a comment line. [...]
>
> 2    If a noncharacter context is to be continued, an “&” shall be the last nonblank character on the line, or the last nonblank character before an “!”. [...]

Comment: I tried it and got this error: 

Error: Syntax error in expression at (1)
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)

Comment: I tried your code again and it works. Thank you! I will try to fix my own code.