# How to put a comma at the end of first line in txt file using awk

Tags: awk

Tried with the command but first line is replaced with comma

```
awk '{if(NR==1){print $0","}else{print }}' /home/a/b/file1.txt
a 
b
c
```

**Expected result**

```
a,
b
c
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Is it possible you have DOS line endings messing up your output? (`cat -e file1.txt` may help determine that)

Comment: Your command should work like a charm.

Comment: @Jerin Just in case, please let know if your issue is solved.

Comment: Please let know what the problem was or still is.

Answer (score 1):

If you have CRLF endings you need to convert them to LF ones, see [How to convert Windows end of line in Unix end of line (CR/LF to LF)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891076).

Then, your solution may work as is. Alternatively, you may use

```
awk '{ print NR==1 ? $0"," : $0 }' /home/a/b/file1.txt > newfile
```

Here, you only `print` the whole line with a `,` at the end if it is the first line, else, you only print the line itself.

If you want, you may also do it with `sed`:

```
sed '1s/$/,/' /home/a/b/file1.txt > newfile
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/wxiinl). Here, `sed` replaces the end of line position with `,` on the first line (so, basically adds the comma). If you use `sed '1s/,*$/,/'` you may make sure there is only 1 comma at the end of the first line in the result.