# Property file showing LF character at end causing shell to pick only one line of the HTML content in props file

Tags: shell, jenkins, notepad++, carriage-return, linefeed

I have HTML template which on enabling the **Show All Characters** in Notepad++ shows this **CR LF** characters:

[image]

After processing and adding the HTML file to property file as one of the values in property file for it to be picked up by Jenkins job as email content, I see that only first line of the value (HTML code) is picked up by Jenkins. On investigating the property file in Notepad++, I could see only **LF** is retained which could be the issue.

[image]

However there is one more job which WORKS FINE by picking all of the ALL of the property value which is also a HTML content. And that has just **CR**

[image]

So I want to ensure that my final property file HTML content has just **CR** and not **CR LF** OR **LF**.

Please advise on how I can do it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert Windows end of line in Unix end of line (CR/LF to LF)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891076/how-to-convert-windows-end-of-line-in-unix-end-of-line-cr-lf-to-lf)

Comment: Replace `\R` with `\r`.

Comment: See the `Edit` menu, option `EOL Conversion`