# How to make grep work iteratively in bash "while read line" function?

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I have a text file (`capital_names.txt`) containing lines like these:

```
Warsaw_  
London_  
Oslo_  
...
```

In another file (`capital_info.txt`) I have the following lines:

```
London_1_  
London_2  
cityLondon_3  
capitalWarsaw_1  
Warsaw_2  
...
```

I wanted to write a shell script that greps capital names only if they are in the following format "Name_".
Desired outputs are multiple files like these:

```
$ cat Warsaw_output.txt  
Warsaw_2

$ cat London_output.txt   
London_1  
London_2
```

Here is the key part of the script:

```
$outp=$"output"  
while read line; do  
grep ^$line capital_info.txt > $line$outp  
done < capital_names.txt
```

However, the output files are empty (0 bytes) and have the following names:

```
'Warsaw_$'\r''output'  
'London_'$'\r''output'
```

When I run individual commands (`grep -f ^"London_" capital_info.txt`) everything works but I cannot do it for 50000 entries in capital_names.txt manually. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: the `\r` characters are windows/dos line endings; consider removing these from your file(s) (eg, `dos2unix filename`) and then run your script again

Comment: There are many problems with the example code.  Use [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to find them, and how to fix them.

Comment: See [Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39527571/4154375) and [How to convert Windows end of line in Unix end of line (CR/LF to LF)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3891076/4154375).

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples and attempts, please try following `awk` code. Written and tested in GNU `awk`, should work in any `awk`.

```
awk '
BEGIN  { FS=OFS="_" }
FNR==NR{
  arr[$1]
  next
}
($1 in arr) && $2~/^[0-9]+$/{
  outFile=($1"_output.txt")
  if(prev!=outFile){ close(prev) }
  print ( $1,$2 ) > (outFile)
  prev=outFile
}
' capital_names.txt capital_info.txt
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                  ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN  { FS=OFS="_" }                  ##In BEGIN section of awk setting FS and OFS as _ here.
FNR==NR{                               ##Checking condition FNR==NR then do following.
  arr[$1]                              ##Creating array arr with index of $1.
  next                                 ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
($1 in arr) && $2~/^[0-9]+$/{          ##Checking if $1 is in arr AND 2nd field is digits.
  outFile=($1"_output.txt")            ##Creating outFile which has output file name in it.
  if(prev!=outFile){ close(prev) }     ##Checking if previous output file name is NOT same as current output file name then close previous one, to avoid too many open files error.
  print ( $1,$2 ) > (outFile)          ##printing 1st and 2nd field to outFile here.
  prev=outFile                         ##Setting prev to outFile value here.
}
' capital_names.txt capital_info.txt   ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Comment: There's a slight problem: closed files will get truncated during the next write. See the content of `test.txt` after running `awk 'BEGIN{f="test.txt"; print "A" > f; close(f); print "B" > f; close(f)}'`. using `>>` would be better (and might require the truncating of the files in `FNR==NR`)

Comment: @Fravadona, files will be closed only when last and current output file names are not same. If I get your comment right here.

Comment: You're probably right by doing it like that; in the provided sample there's only two continuous `Londons_XXX`, so nothing suggests there exists discontinuous entries in `capital_info.txt`

Comment: Thanks for your feedback and detailed explanation.
Unfortunately when I put your code in script.awk (with `#!/usr/bin/awk -f` as top line) and make it executable, I get the following errors: `awk: 3: unexpected character '''
awk: 15: unexpected character '''` when I run it from command line

Comment: @duda13, no you need not to run this as `#!/usr/bin/awk -f` put this whole code starting from `awk` into a shell script and then run it, it should fly then.