# Bash string compare doesn't work if string is coming from WSL command

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using Windows 11 with WSL 2 Ubuntu 18.04 as Guest OS.
I have written the following script as part of `~/.bash_profile` with the intent to set the `PRELUDE_HOST` env variable both in my Ubuntu OS and on the Windows OS:

```
export PRELUDE_HOST=10.10.225.241
WINDOWS_PRELUDE_HOST=`cmd.exe /c echo %PRELUDE_HOST%`
if [[ "$PRELUDE_HOST" != "$WINDOWS_PRELUDE_HOST" ]]
then
    cmd.exe /c setx PRELUDE_HOST $PRELUDE_HOST
fi
```

The first time I run this script - the `PRELUDE_HOST` env is set onto the Windows OS globally.
But for some reason, if I run the script a second time - the string comparison doesn't work as expected and the `cmd.exe /c setx PRELUDE_HOST $PRELUDE_HOST` runs a second time.

I can't figure out why the `if [[ "$PRELUDE_HOST" != "$WINDOWS_PRELUDE_HOST" ]]` comparison is not working as expected. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please add to your question output of: `echo "$WINDOWS_PRELUDE_HOST" | hexdump -C`

Comment: Well apparently the strings are different. Try printing/logging them.

Comment: Output of `cmd.exe` will have CRLF line ending.  The CR will remain after its captured by `` `...` `` (should be `$(...)`).  See [Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39527571/4154375) and [How to convert Windows end of line in Unix end of line (CR/LF to LF)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3891076/4154375).

Comment: Try `"${WINDOWS_PRELUDE_HOST%$'\r'}"` to remove the carriage return.

Comment: Removing the carriage return worked like a charm! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue (WSL generated string versus Linux string saved in a file). Printed out the respective length. They were different by one. Printed each character for the length, unexplainable characters also printed for the WSL string. Had to trim the string by the known length before comparison.