# Bash printf value does not show up or is cut off

Tags: bash, docker, sed, printf

I trying to get a value from a command into a var
and then print it our using `printf`.

**Problem**: i got the value in the var but with printf it does not appear
or is cut off.

*INFO: In my script im calling `redis-cli info memory`

and to check whats wrong i tried a call on `vmstat -s`.*

**Working vmstat test:**

```
format="%-16s | %-16s"
container_name="some_name"
used_memory=$(vmstat -s | sed -n "s/^\(.*\) K used memory.*$/\1/p")
row=$(printf "${format}" "${container_name}" "${used_memory}")
echo "${row}"
```

Output: `some_name        |      11841548`

**The actual script that is not working:**

```
format="%-50s | %-16s"
container_name="totally_secret_container_name_1"
used_memory=$(docker exec -it "${container_name}" redis-cli info memory | sed -n "s/^used_memory_human:\(.*\)$/\1/p")
row=$(printf "${format}" "${container_name}" "${used_memory}")
echo "${row}"
```

Output:          `ecret_container_name_1                    | 1.08M`

Weird is than when i set the format to `format="%-50s | %-1s"`
then it works - the container name (left value) gets printed correctly.

What happen here?
How can i fix this?

*Thanks for your time!*

Comment: There's a carriage return in the output of the command.

Comment: Pipe the command to `od -c` and look for `\r`

Comment: ```used_memory=$(... | sed -n "s/^used_memory_human:\(.*\)$/\1/p" | od -c)``` brings me ```0000000   1   .   0   8   M  \r  \r  \n``` .

Comment: @Barmar So as i read `od -c` is just to see the chars. I now see that i got `\r  \r  \n` at the end of the string. But im not able to remove them. I even tried to not capture them with ```sed -En 's/used_memory_human:([0-9a-zA-Z\.])/\1/gp'``` but it still captures new line and reset(?). How can i get rid of those chars?

Comment: Pipe to `tr -d '\r'`

Comment: @Barmar Yes! =) ```redis-cli info memory | sed -n "s/^used_memory_human:\(.*\)$/\1/p" | tr -d '\r'``` That works. Thank you! You wanna post an anser so i can accept it?

Comment: See [Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39527571/4154375) and [How to convert Windows end of line in Unix end of line (CR/LF to LF)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3891076/4154375).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `\r` characters in the output that are causing it to go back to the beginning of the line and overwrite.

```
used_memory=$(docker exec -it "${container_name}" redis-cli info memory | sed -n "s/^used_memory_human:\(.*\)$/\1/p")
used_memory=${used_memory//$'\r'/}
row=$(printf "${format}" "${container_name}" "${used_memory}")
```

This uses the `bash` `${variable//old/new}` replacement operator.

Comment: This version does not work :/
I dont know what `/$'\r'/` does, but im getting the same cut off string again.

Comment: Sorry, it needs to be `//` to replace all occurrences rather than just the first.