# echo is printing wrong and if is not working

Tags: bash

My bash script is not working properly, i don't know why

test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

CLEAN_FILES=".slug-post-clean"


while read file; do
  [[ ! -n "${file}" ]] && continue

  echo $file

  echo "if [[ -d ${file}]]; then exists ";

  if [[ -d "${file}" ]]; then
    echo "file exists"
  fi

done < ${CLEAN_FILES}
```

.slug-post-clean

```
src
public
node_modules/.cache
```

output

```
src
]]; then exists
public
]]; then exists
node_modules/.cache
]]; then exists dules/.cache
```

But this code works

```
if [[ -d "src" ]]; then
  echo "if works"
fi
```

output

```
if works
```

My Ubuntu version is 20.04LTS

Anyone knows what's happening?

Comment: When I copied your code, I get the following output:
src
if [[ -d src]]; then exists
public
if [[ -d public]]; then exists
node_modules/.cache
if [[ -d node_modules/.cache]]; then exists
I ran it on my Arch Linux desktop, with `bash --version version 5.1.16(1)-release`.

Comment: The file has CRLF line breaks. Fix it with `dos2unix`.

Comment: See [Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39527571/4154375) and [How to convert Windows end of line in Unix end of line (CR/LF to LF)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3891076/4154375).

Comment: dos2unix doesn't works, i have the same output, i'm using linux subsystem for windows(WSL).

Comment: my bash desktop version is ```version 5.0.17(1)-release```, Is there a way to update bash in windows?