# writing loop in bash stops after first iteration

Tags: bash, loops, rename

*New to coding*
I have a very simple loop that Im using to rename files, but it stops after the first iteration.

Im running the loop:

```
for x in `cat list_genomes.txt`
do
        mv -v $x"_busco/run_hypocreales_odb10" "/busco_runs/run_"$x
done
```

and the error I get is:

```
‘FV25228_busco/run_hypocreales_odb10’ -> ‘busco_runs/run_FV25228’
mv: cannot stat ‘\r_busco/run_hypocreales_odb10’: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat ‘FV32968\r_busco/run_hypocreales_odb10’: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat ‘FV34765\r_busco/run_hypocreales_odb10’: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat ‘FV-NC-01\r_busco/run_hypocreales_odb10’: No such file or directory
```

so the first line works, but then it cannot read the rest.

list_genomes.txt looks like:

```
FV25228 
FV32968 
FV34765 
FV-NC-01 
Fc25332
```

Comment: Add sample input from `list_genomes.txt` and expected changes

Comment: Looks like the file has CRLF EOLs. But that’s not a good way to iterate over lines in a file anyway, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521462/looping-through-the-content-of-a-file-in-bash.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29

Comment: For help with the CRLF line endings, see ["Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings) and ["How to convert Windows end of line in Unix end of line (CR/LF to LF)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891076/how-to-convert-windows-end-of-line-in-unix-end-of-line-cr-lf-to-lf)

Answer (score 0):

Your input file has originated on a system that is not identical to the one where you are running the script.

The "**\r**" on the 2nd-5th line indicate that the file came **from a Windows-based system**.  The person who created the file should have chosen a format that is compatible with system on which the data was going to be processed, which in this case **appears to be Unix/Linux based**.

If the creator of your input file doesn't change the way they do that, you need to massage the file before feeding it to your program logic, using the command **dos2unix**.

The following would likely provide you with the necessary fix if all else is correct:

```
#!/bin/bash

dos2unix -n list_genomes.txt list_genomes.fix
while read line
do
        mv -v "${line}_busco/run_hypocreales_odb10" "/busco_runs/run_${line}"
done < list_genomes.fix
```

Comment: `dos2unix` doesn't write anything to stdout, so you can't pipe its output.

Comment: @Benjamin,  I updated per one of the forms allowed, but the stdout is redirected as my original, as per man page for dos2unix.  Look for the string "dos2unix > out.txt" .

Comment: It prints to stdout if it reads from stdin, like `dos2unix < input.txt`; if you give it a filename without redirection, it updates the file in-place (or copies and renames such that it looks like in-place).