# Bash loop to read file line by line problem with sqlcmd

Tags: bash, while-loop, readfile, sqlcmd

I'm reading a .txt file using a while loop:

```bash
baseFileDir=./Base_Database_Files/
if [ -f "./SqlFiles.txt" ]; then
    while IFS= read -r line  || [[ -n "$line" ]]
    do  
        sqlFilePath=${baseFileDir}$line
        echo "Executing: $sqlFilePath"
        sqlcmd -S $server,$port -U $user -P $password -d $database -I -i "$sqlFilePath"  < /dev/null
    done <./SqlFiles.txt
fi
```

`sqlcmd` have problem with `$lin`. Here is the output:

```
Executing: ./Base_Database_Files/MyScript.sql
': Invalid filename.base_Files/MyScript.sql
```

but if I hardcode the line `./Base_Database_Files/MyScript.sql` i.e.

```bash
baseFileDir=./Base_Database_Files/
if [ -f "./SqlFiles.txt" ]; then
    while IFS= read -r line  || [[ -n "$line" ]]
    do  
        sqlFilePath=./Base_Database_Files/MyScript.sql
        echo "Executing: $sqlFilePath"
        sqlcmd -S $server,$port -U $user -P $password -d $database -I -i "$sqlFilePath"  < /dev/null
    done <./SqlFiles.txt
fi
```

it seems to be executing the script properly. i.e.

```
Executing: ./Base_Database_Files/MyScript.sql
Warning! The maximum key length for a nonclustered index is 1700 bytes. The index 'UIX_ALARM_NOTIFICATION_1' has maximum length of 2004 bytes. For some combination of large values, the insert/update operation will fail.
```

> Note:The above `Warning!` is from SQL server depicting that the script was executed properly.

It looks like `sqlcmd` doesn't like the variable `$line` format.

**Question:** How to make `$line` variable used with the `while IFS= read -r line` statement workable/readable by `sqlcmd`?

Comment: The file has CRLF newlines. Fix it with `dos2unix`.

Comment: You could debug this with a simple `echo $line` inside the while loop to make sure the value is what you are expecting.

Comment: You can also get `read` to trim the problematic carriage return with `while IFS=$'\r' read -r ...`. See ["Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings) and ["How to convert Windows end of line in Unix end of line (CR/LF to LF)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891076/how-to-convert-windows-end-of-line-in-unix-end-of-line-cr-lf-to-lf) for more info and options.

Comment: @Nic3500 `echo $line` is *not* a good debugging step, because it can be misleading in a number of ways. For one thing, it doesn't do anything at all about showing invisible/nonprinting characters (like the carriage return that's causing trouble here), and for another the lack of double-quotes around the variable means bash may change it before passing it to `echo`. See ["I just assigned a variable, but echo $variable shows something else"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566). `printf "'%s'\n" "$line" | LC_ALL=C cat -vt` is much better.

Comment: @GordonDavisson, Thanks for the detailed references. I was able to solve it. Please see my posted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

References from the comments posted by @Gordon Davisson and @Barmar, I was able to solve this issue by adding `sed -i 's/\r//g' $SqlFilesList` which would convert the `Dos/Windows CR/LR` to `Unix LF` format: Here is the working snippet:

```bash
    SqlFilesList="./SqlFiles.txt"

    # converting the CR/LF to Unix LF Or sqlcmd won't recognize the paths properly due to Windows CR/LR chars like \r\n.
    sed -i 's/\r//g' $SqlFilesList

    #// Read the file list and concatenate the related Path and execute the .sql files.

    if [ -f $SqlFilesList ]; then
        while IFS=$'\r' read -r line  || [[ -n "$line" ]]
        do  
            printf "\nExecuting: %s\n" "$line"
            sqlcmd -S $server,$port -U $user -P $password -d $database -I -i "$line"  < /dev/null 
        done < $SqlFilesList
    else
        echo "The file $database/$SqlFilesList is missing, which should contain the sequence of *.sql to be executed."
        exit 1
    fi
```