# Search keywords in master csv if keyword exist then update input csv 2nd column with value true or false

Tags: bash, shell, csv, sh

Input csv - new_param.csv

value like -

```
ID
Identity
as-uid
cp_cus_id
evs
k_n
```

master.csv has value like -

```
A, xyz, id, abc
n, xyz, as-uid, abc, B, xyz, ne, abc
q, xyz, id evs, abc
3, xyz, k_n, abc, C, xyz, ad, abc
1, xyz, zd, abc
z, xyz, ID, abc
```

Require Output Updated new_param.csv - true or false in 2nd column

```
ID,true
Identity,false
as-uid,true
cp_cus_id,false
evs,true
k_n,true
```

tried below code no output -

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a keywords=(`cat new_param.csv`)
 
length=${#keywords[@]}

for (( j=0; j<length; j++ ));
do
 a= LC_ALL=C awk -v kw="${keywords[$j]}" -F, '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i ~ kw) {print i}}' master.csv
b=0
if [ $a -gt $b ]
then
  echo true $2 >> new_param.csv
else
  echo false $2 >> new_param.csv
fi
done
```

Please help someone !

Tried above mention code but does not helping me

getings error like -

`test.sh: line 29: [: -gt: unary operator expected test.sh: line 33: -f2: command not found`

Comment: please help anyone :pray:

Comment: cut-n-paste your code into [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) and make the recommended code changes; in this particular case variable `a` is empty (`a= `) and because of missing double quotes `[ $a -gt $b ]` becomes `[  -gt $b ]` hence the error message

Comment: @markp-fuso my bad it's sample data, updated !!

Comment: @markp-fuso if I add double quotes used like `if [ "$a" -gt "$b" ]` then get error 
 `test.sh: line 29: [: : integer expression expected`

Comment: line numbers from the error messages don't match the code you've posted, and we're not shown the script invocation so we don't know what `$2` contains ... so it's hard to tell what the 2nd error message (re: `-f2`) is referring to; consider updating the question with the code that generated the error messages, or update the error message(s) based on running the code you've supplied here; also provide the value of `$2`

Comment: yes, adding the double quotes generates a new error message ... which is (still) tied to the fact that `a` is empty; assuming `a` is supposed to contain the output from the `awk` call ...  to try `a=$(LC_ALL=C awk ...)`

Comment: @markp-fuso tired `a=$(LC_ALL=C awk -v kw="${keywords[$j]}" -F, '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i ~ kw) {print i}}' master.csv)
b=0
if [ "$a" -gt "$b" ]`    error is test.sh: line 29: [: : integer expression expected

Comment: and ... what's in `a`? what is the output from `typeset -p a`? does `a` contain what you're expecting it to contain?

Comment: @markp-fuso I want to use `a` command to check keyword exist in csv or not but for now I am using this command to find column no of csv that has value contains  with passing keyword it give me output like `36
36
46
36`

Comment: @markp-fuso in case if keyword not exist in csv then it me blank no out type

Comment: `-gt` is a numeric comparison operator; *you* need to insure both `a` and `b` contain numbers (actually, integers since `bash` only works with integers); if `a` and/or `b` are empty or non-integer then you will get an error; at this point *you* need to review your design (eg, do you want to compare integers or strings?) and then update your code to match your design requirements

Comment: @markp-fuso can you suggest for any other solution for - check keyword exist in csv or not if exist then update or add 2nd column in input csv with any type of identifier like 0 or 1 and true or false

Comment: should `evs` (from `master.csv1) match on the string `XevsY`? or are you looking for exact word matches?

Comment: @markp-fuso exact word contains in column

Comment: See [Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39527571/4154375) and [How to convert Windows end of line in Unix end of line (CR/LF to LF)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3891076/4154375).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `grep` to find exact word matches:

```
$ grep -owf new_param.csv master.csv | sort -u
ID
as-uid
evs
k_n
```

Then feed this to `awk` to match against `new_param.csv` entries:

```
awk '
BEGIN   { OFS="," }
FNR==NR { a[$1]; next }
        { print $1, ($1 in a) ? "true" : "false" }
' <(grep -owf new_param.csv master.csv | sort -u) new_param.csv
```

This generates:

```
ID,true
Identity,false
as-uid,true
cp_cus_id,false
evs,true
k_n,true
```

Once the results are confirmed as correct OP can add `> new_param.csv` to the end of the `awk` script, eg:

```
awk 'BEGIN { OFS="," } FNR==NR ....' <(grep -owf ...) new_parame.csv > new_param.csv
                                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: `grep -owf new_param.csv master.csv | sort -u` it return only `evs`

Comment: using the files you've provided ... that `grep|sort` returns 4 rows ... `ID`, `as-uid`, `evs` and `k_n`; I'm wondering if there are some non-printing characters in one/both of your files; consider reviewing the output from `head -2 new_param.csv master.csv | od -c` for any odd characters (eg, `\r`)

Comment: `0000000    =   =   >       n   e   w   _   p   a   r   a   m   .   c   s
0000020    v       <   =   =  \n   I   D  \r  \n   I   d   e   n   t   i
0000040    t   y  \r  \n  \n   =   =   >       R   o   p   a   .   c   s
0000060    v       <   =   =  \n   A   ,       x   y   z   ,       i   d
0000100    ,       a   b   c   ,   ,   ,   ,  \r  \n   n   ,       x   y
0000120    z   ,       a   s   -   u   i   d   ,       a   b   c   ,    
0000140    B   ,       x   y   z   ,       n   e   ,       a   b   c  \r
0000160   \n                                                            
`

Comment: yeah, you've got windows/dos line endings (`\r`) in your files; try removing these characters via `dos2unix *.csv`

Comment: this command not for mac os is it? `dos2unix *.csv` `zsh: command not found: dos2unix
`

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -v RS=', |\n' 'NR == FNR { a[$0] = 1; next }
        { gsub(/,.*/, ""); b = "" b $0 (a[$0] ? ",true" : ",false") "\n" }
        END { if (FILENAME == "new_param.csv") printf "%s", b > FILENAME }' master.csv new_param.csv
```

Comment: it return only one keyword as true `ID 
 FALSE
Identity 
 FALSE
as-uid 
 FALSE
cp_cus_id 
 FALSE
evs 
 FALSE
k_n TRUE`

Comment: @ASHOKDAUKIYA The problem is you keep revising your examples and requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Try this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean pure Bash code:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

outputs=()

while read -r kw; do
    if grep -q -E "(^|[[:space:],])$kw([[:space:],]|\$)" master.csv; then
        outputs+=( "$kw,true" )
    else
        outputs+=( "$kw,false" )
    fi
done <new_param.csv

printf '%s\n' "${outputs[@]}" >new_param.csv
```

- You may need to tweak the regular expression used with `grep -E` depending on what exactly you want to count as a match.

Comment: it return false for all keyword `ID 
 FALSE
Identity 
 FALSE
as-uid 
 FALSE
cp_cus_id 
 FALSE`

Comment: I tested the code  with the files that you specified before I posted it.  You are either not using the code that I provided or you are running it with different files.  There is absolutely no way that the code could generate output with `FALSE` instead of `false` and no commas.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative `awk` option:

Use a `,`  for the field separator and concatenate the 3rd field for each record of the `master.csv` to the variable `m`.  Second, read each record from the `new-params.csv` file and use the `index` funtion to determine whether that record exists in the `m` variable string.

```
 awk -F", " '
FNR==NR{m=m$3}
FNR<NR{print $0 (index(m,$0) ? ",true" : ",false")}                           
' master.csv new-params.csv
```

Output:

```
ID,true
Identity,false
as-uid,true
cp_cus_id,false
evs,true
k_n,true
```