# Bash - A single command line that changes a hash file and gives it in input to sha512Sum

Tags: bash, concatenation, echo

I have a hash file that contains only the digest:

```
cat archive.hash
DBD47245A6E78626CBAD9A228C8956741BBA853E9D4A1DFCA6E335366C438C26341321E83B614834F78CD4D8FF71B05D5ADE8FAB3E0ECE5EF34A486D09882BB7
```

In order to accept the hash file as input and check, the **sha512sum** command requires that the file is formatted with a low chars digest followed by two spaces and the file name:

```
9a228c8956741bba853e9d4a1dfca6e335366c438c26341321e83b614834f78cd4d8ff71b05d5ade8fab3e0ece5ef34a486d09882bb7  archive.zip
```

I tried several syntax such as:

```
 sha512sum -c <(echo "$(cat archive.hash |tr A-Z a-z) archive.zip")
```

But I receive this error:

```
sha512sum: /dev/fd/63: no properly formatted SHA512 checksum lines found
```

Analyzing the string:

```
echo "$(cat archive.hash |tr A-Z a-z) archive.zip"
```

The output is this:

```
archive.zip9a228c8956741bba853e9d4a1dfca6e335366c438c26341321e83b614834f78cd4d8ff71b05d5ade8fab3e0ece5ef34a486d09882bb7
```

It put the file name in front of the hash digest. How can this problem be avoided?

Comment: **Your file has a CRLF line ending** perhaps because it came from or was editted on Windows. Look at it with `cat -vE` or `od -c` or `sed -n l` (that's ell not one) to see/confirm. Remove the CR with `dos2unix` or `tr -d '\r'` or `sed 's/\r$//'`. Note you don't put 2 spaces, but the `shasum` format doesn't actually require 2 spaces just 1.

Comment: `How can this problem be avoided?` Your file has dos line endings. Remove them. It can be avoided by not adding them.

Comment: See the "Before asking about problematic code" section of the [Stack Overflow 'bash' Info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info).

Comment: Also see [Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39527571/4154375) and [How to convert Windows end of line in Unix end of line (CR/LF to LF)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3891076/4154375).

Comment: I didn't know it was a file generated by a Windows system. I managed to solve the problem with this syntax:

`sha512sum -c <(echo "$(cat archive.hash |dos2unix|tr A-Z a-z) archive.zip")`