# Bash script - how to create dynamic value

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

This is bash script

```
#!/bin/sh

filename=$1
path=data/$filename/$filename.csv
echo $path

aws s3 cp s3://bucket/key/$filename.csv $path
```

we written it for based on input parameter (filename), read the file from s3 bucket and move to our local directory. for example `sh demo.sh sales` . it will copy sales.csv file from source s3 bucket to local directory data/sales/sales.csv.

when we execute the command , it is showing some wired output like this .`csvsales`. but my expectation is data/sales/sales.csv.  I tried ${filename},$filename and add double /. no luck,. But one think observed is if have this line

```
path=data/$filename/
```

and do echo it is printing data/sales. if i add additional string '/$filename.csv' it is not showing expected output.

Comment: Try pasting your code into shellcheck.net Note also that it is `bash` ***not*** `batch`.

Comment: OMG. modified it

Comment: It looks to me like something -- maybe the script, maybe its input, maybe both -- is in DOS/Windows format, rather than unix format. See ["Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings) and ["How to convert Windows end of line in Unix end of line (CR/LF to LF)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891076/how-to-convert-windows-end-of-line-in-unix-end-of-line-cr-lf-to-lf).

Comment: Tangentially, see also [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable) Your script will break if a user passes in an argument with spaces or other shell metacharacters.