# Output of echo disappears with variable in String in bash

Tags: bash

I am reading in a file: `data.txt` containing lines like

```
B07G1W8SHN
B007E2L6G4
B07GXQS5DW
B06XBRP5WY
```

when I am reading a line of that file and put the variable `$line` into some context

```
read line < data.txt
echo "context${line}context"
```

I get the following output:

```
contextB07G1W8SHN
```

what is happening here? I guess there are some hidden `delete-characters` is my string?
How can I read the lines in a variable as a plain string?

`xxd data.txt` output:

```
00000000: 4230 3747 3157 3853 484e 0d0a 4230 3037  B07G1W8SHN..B007
00000010: 4532 4c36 4734 0d0a 4230 3747 5851 5335  E2L6G4..B07GXQS5
00000020: 4457 0d0a 4230 3658 4252 5035 5759 0d0a  DW..B06XBRP5WY..
```

Comment: Please provide the output of `xxd data.txt` otherwise we'd have to guess what's going on.

Comment: the output is `00000000: 4230 3747 3157 3853 484e 0d0a 4230 3037  B07G1W8SHN..B007
00000010: 4532 4c36 4734 0d0a 4230 3747 5851 5335  E2L6G4..B07GXQS5
00000020: 4457 0d0a 4230 3658 4252 5035 5759 0d0a  DW..B06XBRP5WY`

Comment: Also see [Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39527571/4154375) and [How to convert Windows end of line in Unix end of line (CR/LF to LF)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3891076/4154375).

Comment: Those `0d0a` sequences in the `xxd` dump are a carriage return (`0d`) and linefeed (`0a`), which is the DOS/Windows convention for line delimiters. You can trim the carriage return in the `read` command with `IFS=$'\r' read line < data.txt`. See the links pjh gave for lots more info and options to deal with this.