# Trying to mass edit folder names with bash script - getting weird result

Tags: linux, bash, shell, rename

I'm trying to use CVS comma delimited replacement for a bunch of folder names on an Ubuntu using bash.

I'm running the following:

```
dir='/home/company/customer'

while IFS=, read -r oldStr newStr; do

      find "$dir" -type d -name "$oldStr" -max depth 1 execdir mv -n "$dir/$oldStr/" "$dir/$newStr/" \;

done < exceltest.csv
```

I run this and it works, however the result is weird. When I cd to the directory, the resulting folder names in the CLI are 'newname1'$\r', 'newname2'$\r', 'newname3'$\r', etc...

However when I open the folder location via the folder GUI, the folder names are correct: newname1, newname2, newname3.

Is my script causing this weird naming convention and how do I avoid this? I'm worried about leaving this is a mess for future scripts.

Thanks!

Comment: This looks like a line ending problem. Has your script been edited on a windows machine, or is your text editor configured to use CLRF endings ?

Comment: See [How to convert Windows end of line in Unix end of line (CR/LF to LF)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3891076/4154375).

Comment: Also see [Why does my tool output overwrite itself and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45772525/4154375).

Comment: Hmm it looks like it is from an issue from creating the code&csv on a MacOS before moving it over to test on the Linux. Line ending problem seems to be the issue thanks!