# Can't capture output of find + grep in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I'm hitting my head against the wall here with this...
I'm trying to create a simple script that loads a file as an array, and searches for each line through files whether there is a match.

- If a match is found, do nothing
- If no match is found, write the entry to a file

The script looks something like this:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "Please enter the full path to the directory where the log files are located:"
read -r log_directory

readarray -t lines < mac-addresses.txt

echo "Loaded ${#lines[@]} mac addresses to search for."

for mac_address in "${lines[@]}"
do
  found=$(find "$log_directory" -name 'dhcpd.log.[1-30]' -exec grep "$mac_address" {} + | wc -l)

  echo "Result for $mac_address $count"
done
```

This is what happens when I call the script:

```
Please enter the full path to the directory where the log files are located:
./logs
Loaded 2 mac addresses to search for.
0
 esult for d4:3d:7e:ce:24:14
0
 esult for 00:12:34:56:78:9a
```

1. Why is the output from the `echo` command mangled?
2. How do I capture the output from `find "$log_directory" -name 'dhcpd.log.[1-30]' -exec grep "$mac_address" {} + | wc -l` ?

I've tried using `$()`, tried using backticks, but I can't really seem to capture the command correctly.
Here's an output example:

```
$ find "./logs" -name 'dhcpd.log.[1-30]' -exec grep "d4:3d:7e:ce:24:14" {} + | wc -l
3

arned@Saturn MINGW64 /d/src/Scripts/mac-address-searcher
$ find "./logs" -name 'dhcpd.log.[1-30]' -exec grep "00:12:34:56:78:9a" {} + | wc -l
0
```

So the command is doing exactly what I want, but I just can't get it to work correctly inside my bash script...

Comment: Your file has dos line endings or even other invisible characters. Both the script and mac-addresses.txt .

Comment: That's possible as these are mixed Windows and Linux files. Good catch, let me see if I can clean that out.

Comment: @KamilCuk you were right, stripping/cleaning the entries solved the issue

Comment: Also see [Why does my tool output overwrite itself and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45772525/4154375) and [How to convert Windows end of line in Unix end of line (CR/LF to LF)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3891076/4154375).

Comment: It looks like you're capturing the output you want in the variable `$found` but you're echoing the variable `$count` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit goes to @KamilCuk for pointing out the issue with Windows:

```bash
# Remove special characters from Windows such as the carriage return.
# Otherwise the search will fail as the input gets messed up.
cleaned_entry=${mac_address//$'\r'}
```

Since the input file comes from a Windows system, the carriage return needs to be removed for each entry. This makes the commands work correctly.