# How to convert files from Dos to Unix

Tags: java, dos2unix

I am having several files which I want to convert from Dos to Unix. Is there any API or method which will help me to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert DOS/Windows newline (CRLF) to Unix newline (\n) in a Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613800/how-to-convert-dos-windows-newline-crlf-to-unix-newline-n-in-a-bash-script)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are linux tools that can do this ([`dos2unix`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dos2unix) for example).

In Java it can be done with [`String.replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

DOS uses `\r\n` for line termination, while UNIX uses a single `\n`.

```
String unixText = windowsText.replaceAll("\r\n", "\n"); // DOS2UNIX
```

So no, no API exists. Yes, it is dead easy.

Comment: Do i need to open all files one by one and replaceAll("\r\n", "\n").

Comment: Yes, of course. Please also note that this only makes sense for ASCII text files!

Answer (score 2):

There is a utility/command in Linux/Unix called `dos2unix` that will help you convert your files from dos to unix format. To install simply type in console(you may need root privileges)

```
yum install dos2unix
```

To do the conversion you have to use command dos2unix followed by filename. For example

```
[aniket@localhost ~]$ dos2unix sample.txt 
dos2unix: converting file sample.txt to UNIX format ...
```

For all files in a directory you can simply use

```
dos2unix *
```

Comment: I don't know why this answer was down-voted. It did, after all, indicate the package name to use when installing from `yum`, which none of the other answers noted.

Comment: @GarretWilson Because that is not Java as stated in the tags (hello from the future :D )

Answer (score 2):

Just an alternate way (than the one parasietje described) using dox2unix. Say you all dos files are in one folder

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("dos2unix /path/to/dos/files/*");
```

Answer (score 1):

Most unix/linux distributions have utility named `unix2dos` and `dos2unix` commands.

EDIT:
Just copy your file to unix machine and run `dos2unix *`.

You can also find this utility for Windows and do the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
String unixText = windowsText.replaceAll("\r\n", "\n"); // DOS2UNI
```

The above line should remove all \r but for some reason it also removes the \n so I had to add it back when printing unixText to a file:
    unixText + "\n"