# Java | CSV issue with ^M

Tags: java, csv

I have problem with this annoying ^M, while exporting some data, writing it to a CSV file to be downloaded. I did some research and found out that if the file you are reading comes from a Windows system this issue happens (Windows uses CR (i.e. ^M)/LF pair to indicate the end of a line, while UNIX uses only a LF).

Now can anyone offer me a solution to overcome this problem (like eliminating or replacing ^M ) before putting it to the writer (writer.write(columnToBeInserted);)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `unix2dos` and `dos2unix` to convert UNIX and Windows files respectively. Both are available on *nix and Windows platforms. Read [more](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/nix/entry/dos2unix_and_unix2dos_converting_between_dos_and_unix_part_12?lang=en).

Links for Windows

- [Dos2Unix](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dos2unix/)
- [Unix2Dos](http://download.cnet.com/Unix2DOS/3000-2381_4-10488164.html)

Also see [How to convert files from Dos to Unix in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9374991/how-to-convert-files-from-dos-to-unix-in-java)

Comment: Could you please provide an example so that I can use in my java code?

Comment: @ComeRun See the last link

Comment: Mate,Since this is a problem reported by one our customer, would u be able to instruct me on how to reproduce this char? like i need to send a text message using fronend and then create a report of that message (as CSV), I need to type something in the message textarea to create that issue and I am not sure how! any special code or something?

Comment: I'd say create a text file on Windows and FTP to Linux. Open with `vi` to view CTRL chars. Any code that uses, say a `PrintWriter` running on Windows _should_ produce the same result.

Comment: To create on `Linux`, write a file containing `"\r\n"` line separators.

Answer (score 1):

As you read each line do

```
line.replaceAll("\\p{Cntrl}", "");
```

Or use a tool to do it for you

Comment: Amir I m using a linux environment and I dont know how to reproduce this char to test your suggestion. would u be able to tell me if there is any special code to reproduce this ^M char?

Answer (score 0):

in linux/unix environment there is a utilities called `dos2unix` and `unix2dos` which converts the files from windows to linux format and vise versa .

on windows check this link and download the utility whch will convert from windows to linux format http://www.sg-chem.net/u2win/

Comment: Can u please provide me with an example so that I can use in my java code? thanks

Comment: this is not done through java code. you pass the filename.java to as a command argument to this utility and it will do the conversion, you do this before commiting your code to csv