# How to set jsch terminal mode?

Tags: java, jsch

I am using **jsch-0.1.50.jar** lib for sftp to Upload and Download and they already work fine but i need to control the terminal mode as **bin** and **ascii** mode. How can I set this terminal mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jsch does not support ascii transfers.  If you want to convert between different text file types, you will have to do it programatically.  If it is a unix/windows issue, check out this article [How to convert files from Dos to Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9374991/how-to-convert-files-from-dos-to-unix-in-java)