# tomcat startup script error

Tags: linux, tomcat, centos

i needed to change the tomcat process to be executed by non root user. created user **tomcat** and put that in **tomcat_group** group. changed permissions. and then changed the startup script in **init.d**.

My old script which is running as a root user is

```
#!/bin/bash
# description: Tomcat Start Stop Restart
# processname: tomcat
# chkconfig: 234 20 80
JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_31
export JAVA_HOME
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH
CATALINA_HOME=/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.26


case $1 in
start)
sh $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh
;; 
stop)   
sh $CATALINA_HOME/bin/shutdown.sh
;; 
restart)
sh $CATALINA_HOME/bin/shutdown.sh
sh $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh
;; 
esac    
exit 0
```

This is running fine as a root user.

New script is that

```
    #!/bin/bash
# description: Tomcat Start Stop Restart
# processname: tomcat
# chkconfig: 234 20 80
JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_31
export JAVA_HOME
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH
CATALINA_HOME=/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.26/bin


case $1 in
start)
/bin/su tomcat $CATALINA_HOME/startup.sh
;; 
stop)   
/bin/su tomcat $CATALINA_HOME/shutdown.sh
;; 
restart)
/bin/su tomcat $CATALINA_HOME/shutdown.sh
/bin/su tomcat $CATALINA_HOME/startup.sh
;; 
esac    
exit 0
```

but this gives error when start my **service**
unable to find whats the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely a result of changing the `$CATALINA_HOME` variable to be the `/bin`.

The `startup.sh`  calls the `catalina.sh` script which depends on the `$CATALINA_HOME` being a specific directory.  I'd definitely recommend changing it back to `CATALINA_HOME=/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.26` and then adding `/bin` back into the command calls.  Tomcat relies heavily on the `CATALINA_HOME` environment variable.

Hope that helps.

EDIT: You still need to take into account Mat's answer, this should just fix the file not found error you are now getting.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old question, but this answer might benefit someone.

I had the same issue with the "No such file or directory". I ran the service command as a shell script
`$> /etc/init.d/tomcat stop`
which returned: 
`-bash: /etc/init.d/tomcat: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

Because I created the script in Windows environment it had Windows line endings. As soon as I fixed that, Tomcat could be started as a service without problems.

This article might help with line changing [How to convert DOS/Windows newline (CRLF) to Unix newline (\n) in a Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613800/how-to-convert-dos-windows-newline-crlf-to-unix-newline-n-in-bash-script)

Comment: Great tip!  This one saved me.

Answer (score 2):

`su` needs a `-c` if you want to start a command with it:

```
/bin/su tomcat -c whatever_command
```

Comment: shows this error:
env: /etc/init.d/tomcat: No such file or directory

Comment: i have a script in "etc/init.d" with the name of tomcat. and run "service tomcat start"

Comment: Does that error still happen if you comment out the `su` lines?