# NEWLINE in windows going to UNIX

Tags: php, windows, unix, porting

I am developing on `PHP`and`APACHE` on windows `xampp` environment.
I have some files I read and write to.
I do use definitions of NEWLINES (`\r\n` for Windows, `\n` for UNIX), but isn't it that when I port to UNIX I am going to have to convert all these files to UNIX text formats?
Is this not a door to lots of weird annoying bugs ?

Thanks

Comment: If you do not convert your files to appropriate newlines for a given environment, you are likely to encounter weird, annoying bugs.

Comment: You should open file in binary mode while writing to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can be any annoying problem. You will need address it somehow. I wrote my own C++ utility using fstream/sstream, but there are lots of solutions out there. There's actually a stack overflow which mentions a few ways to do this:

[How to convert DOS/Windows newline (CRLF) to Unix newline (\n) in a Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613800/how-to-convert-dos-windows-newline-to-unix-newline-in-bash-script)