# Replace bytes in big file using Linux command line

Tags: linux, file, command-line, line-endings

I have a set of big (>1Gb) binary files which was uploaded to FTP with incorrect line-ending. They contain "0D 0A" where should be "0D". Is there a way in Linux to replace all includings of bytes "0D 0A" to "0D" in command line?

Comment: related: [How to convert DOS/Windows newline to Unix newline in bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2613800/4279)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian There is a difference between removing bytes and replacing, I would like to replace, not delete. And it is impossible to install non-standard utilities. Only sed, bash, tr is available...

Comment: I don't understand your comment e.g., in what way `sed $'s/\r$//'` fails for you? There could be invalid for your use-case answers but the question is 100% related.

Comment: I've noticed that instead of replacing `\r\n` with `\n`, you want replace `\r\n` with `\r`. Is it correct?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Yes, I wrote about I need for \r, but actually I am looking for relatively universal solution for replacement bytes. I've tried everything already and didn't get any positive result. But thanks, your comment would be best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The name of the tools are:

`fromdos`

`todos`

They are in the package `tofrodos` in most distributions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command [`dos2unix`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dos2unix). The inverse is [`unix2dos`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/unix2dos), of course.