# Unix Script: Appending two variables from a sourced file not working

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I can't understand this...
I have .sh file with variables (varsource.sh)

```
var1=AppleOrange
var2=Mango
```

Now I am sourcing my varsource.sh in my test.sh script

```
#!/bin/ksh
. ./varsource.sh
appended=$var1$var2
echo $appended
varloc1=aPPLEoRANGE
varloc2=mANGO
locappended=$varloc1$varloc2
echo $locappended
```

The output of above script is

```
MangoOrange
aPPLEoRANGEmANGO
```

I expected similar behavior when I use variables from sourced file and variables local to my script. 
In case of variables from sourced file, the second variable is replacing characters of the first variable instead of appending.

More observations:

```
  . ./varsource.sh
    appended=${var1}xx
    echo $appended
```

Output: xxpleOrange

But appending to left end of the variable is working

```
. ./varsource.sh
appended=xx$var1
echo $appended
```

Output:xxAppleOrange

Could some one help me understand this behaviour? What should I do to perform the appending in case of sourced variables?

Comment: If you need assistance in how to remove the CR, shout.  However, there are questions on SO that discuss many ways to do it, such as [How to convert DOS/Windows newline to Unix newline in a Bash script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613800/how-to-convert-dos-windows-newline-to-unix-newline-in-bash-script/).

Comment: @Jonathan Thanks it Worked. I replaced CR using **tr -d '\015' <DOS-file >UNIX-file**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on a Windows machine, or the sourced file was created on a Windows machine.

Your line endings are CRLF, carriage return and line feed, DOS/Windows style.  The shell treats the carriage return as a regular character, not as part of the 'end of line'.

Remove the carriage returns and all will go back to normal.