# Unexpected $'\r': command not found after mysql query in shell

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

This scipt gives proper result, but also gives mistake:$'\r': command not found in line with query.

```
#!/bin/bash
keyOrPass=$1
intercom=$2
flat=$3
number=$4
mysql -ulogin -ppass dbname -e "select cli.codeGuestEmail, cli.codePrivateEmail, cliKey.rf_id, cliKey.emailNotification from mbus_clients as cli join mbusClientKeys as cliKey on cliKey.id_client=cli.id WHERE cli.flat=${flat} and cli.domophone=${intercom};";
```

This is how I run the script:

```
 sh sendEmailNotification.sh key 10001014 11 1
```

Comment: And how do you call this script? you should detect the number of arguments and is lower than 4 then exit the script without executing the query

Comment: Added example of run.

Comment: Has all the hallmarks of a Windows newline. Was the script created on Windows and copied over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a version of your script without Windows line delimiter `\r`:

```
tr -d "\r" < sendEmailNotification.sh > sendEmailNotification_fixed.sh
```

Comment: You should see the Windows line delimiters with `cat -v sendEmailNotification.sh`.

Answer (score 0):

Check and fix line-endings in your script, probably, it was saved with `\r\n` as line delimiters.

This link may be useful: [How to convert DOS/Windows newline (CRLF) to Unix newline (\n) in a Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613800/how-to-convert-dos-windows-newline-to-unix-newline-in-bash-script)

Comment: But it is in one line in my script.