# Why getting error in bash for loop?

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop

I am trying to run the below code using for loop but i am getting syntax error. Please help.

**Input Format:**
The first line of the input contains an integer N, indicating the number of integers. The next line contains N space-separated integers that form the array A.

```
read n
sum=0

for (( i=1; i<= "$n" ; i++ ))
do
        read val
        sum ^= $val;
done

echo $sum
```

Below is the error message

```
solution.sh: line 4: ((: i<= 1
 : syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "
 ")
```

Comment: DOS line-endings in your script file?

Comment: @EtanReisner Sorry, I did't get what you are asking.

Comment: @User112638726 Using `$` is valid in that context though (despite being unnecessary most of the time) and is not the error.

Comment: See the first suggested item in the "Before asking about problematic code" section of the [bash tag info wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info).

Comment: @User112638726 I am get error when I follow you
solution.sh: line 4: ((: 1
: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "
")

Comment: @User112638726 Nope. Works just fine. Try it yourself.

Comment: @EtanReisner Just checked and neither is an error, but they both still aren't needed (p.s. im dumb).

Comment: @User112638726 Right. Both "incorrect" in that they aren't necessary or helpful but also not the problem.

Comment: As chatraed points out in their answer you also have a spacing problem in the loop body. You **cannot** put spaces around the assignment operator in shell assignments. So `sum ^= $val` is an error and must be written as `((sum^=$val))` but that's not the error being asked about here (the `((...))` is for arithmetic context).

Comment: @chepner yep, i've deleted my other comment as after looking it up it was completely wrong :)

Comment: Further, you'd have to write `((sum^=val))`; it's only valid inside an arithmetic context.

Comment: Add `printf "%s" "$n" | hexdump -C` before the while loop; what output does it produce?

Comment: @chepner 
00000000  31 0d                                             |1.|
00000002
0

Comment: The `0d` is a carriage return. Your script file contains DOS newlines as suggested by Etan. Run `dos2unix` on your script, or use your favorite text editor to save the file with Unix newlines.

Comment: @chepner: nice debug technique!

Comment: how can I convert that code in Unix newline?. I am running the code on a online complier. so running as dos2unix solution.sh not possible

Comment: @Kikit: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613800/how-to-convert-dos-windows-newline-crlf-to-unix-newline-n-in-bash-script).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem (DOS line endings) is covered in the [bash tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info).

Answer (score 1):

The `printf "%s" "$n" | hexdump -C` shows that the CR is contained in the input rather than in the script file, so running `dos2unix` on the script won't help anyway. A simple means to get rid of it is setting `IFS=$'\r'`.
Then, `read val` in a loop is unfit to read *space-separated integers*, since `read` reads a whole line at a time. But for the task of bitwise exclusive ORing those *N space-separated integers* we don't need an explicit loop - we can just replace all spaces with the desired operator and evaluate the result.

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=$'\r'
read n
read a
((sum = ${a// /^}))
echo $sum
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work. However you should insert some helper messages inside:

```
#!/bin/bash

read n
sum=0

for (( i=1; i<=n; i++ ))
do
        read val
        ((sum^=val))
done
echo $sum
```

Comment: `^=` is a valid bash arithmetic context assignment operator (though not with the spaces obviously) but this doesn't solve the actual problem the poster is having.

Comment: Still getting this error

solution.sh: line 4: ((: 1
: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "
")

Comment: It look like there is problem with for loop. why it is giving invalid arithmetic operator?

Comment: @Kikit: try `dos2unix solution.sh` and the rerunning my example. Etan Reisner: thanks for the note (corrected).