# Call a function from an external script

Tags: bash

I have 2 scripts:

**/home/bin/test.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
. /home/bin/test_functions.sh
test
```

**/home/bin/test_functions.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
test()
{
    echo "this is a test"
}
```

I wanted to call the function from the external script and execute it in the main script. Yet I've been receiving these **errors**:

```
'home/bin/test_functions.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `
'home/bin/test_functions.sh: line 2: `test()
```

What could be wrong with what I'm doing?

Comment: This works for me.  Something might be wrong with your file.  Does each one have execute permission?

Comment: Don't use the name `test`; it is a shell built-in command (and also usually an executable found in either `/bin` or `/usr/bin`) and that will confuse you even if it doesn't confuse the shell.

Comment: Yes, I've already changed the permissions for both files in 755.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler i've already tried a different function name yet i still got the same errors and `./test.sh: line 3: testfunc: command not found`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that `test_functions.sh` is in DOS format and bash is choking on the `\r\n` line endings. [Use `dos2unix`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613800/how-to-convert-dos-windows-newline-crlf-to-unix-newline-n-in-bash-script) to convert it to UNIX line endings.

You can tell because what bash is trying to output is this:

```
/home/bin/test_functions.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `\r'
/home/bin/test_functions.sh: line 2: `test()\r'
```

But the carriage returns `\r` cause the single quotes to end up at the beginning of the error messages, overwriting the leading `/`.

Comment: how would i be able to do that? i really don't know much yet since i'm still a newbie.

Comment: @User122113: There are a lot of questions and answers on SO about converting between Windows and DOS format, but John already told you one way — the `dos2unix` command.

Comment: The bash tag wiki talks about this also.

Comment: One such question is [How to convert DOS/Windows newline CRLF to Unix newline '\n' in a Bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613800/)