# Change shell script files generated through Jenkins maven plugins newline character "CRLF" to Linux format "LF"

Tags: linux, shell, maven, jenkins, cmd

I have a Jenkins installed on win servers and I'm building some artifacts through Jenkins maven build plugins.

The `.sh` files included in this build.zip file have a windows format newline characters `CRLF`. How can I get linux format newline characters using Jenkins?

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2613800/2244664

Comment: Thanks @JoaoMorais this will help :)