# is there a difference between uploading csv files from a mac or windows using php

Tags: php, csv

I have built an application which takes a csv file and processes it, saving all the interesting bits to my database.

The source of the csv file is an excel file which I have to download from a 3rd party website. In order to make it csv is simply save it as so in open office and bobs your uncle.

So when I do this from either my windows or linux machine, the files I create upload as expected no bother, however when my colleague does similar on his mac, then we have problems.

I know there are some differences between the the formats of the csv but surely once you've put the file through

```
$csvData = file_get_contents($file);
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $csvData);
$arrayOfLinesAndCols = array();
foreach ($lines as $line) {
   $arrayOfLinesAndCols[] = str_getcsv($line);
}
```

then the output should be the same. The files we are both uploading 'look' the same when you open them.

Comment: So what would those problems look like?Is the data identical?

Comment: Why don't you let your colleague give you the file and analyze it?

Comment: It probably depends. `PHP_EOL` is a representation of the default `end of line` character for _that particular system it is running on_, but if the file is made on another system it won't match. If open office always uses a windows return, the file will look the same (as macs are made to be interoperable), but the end of line character is different on each system...

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're having? And the differences I can think of are: encoding (when saving), delimiter, string delimiter and of course end-line characters.

Comment: You need to run the script on the OS that saved the `.csv` file as PHP_EOL means `0D 0A` on windows and just `0D` on UNIX and some MAC's use something else completely and not all MAC use the same

Comment: Unix/Linux uses `0A` and Mac uses `0D` for end-of-line. Windows uses `0D 0A`.

Comment: Yea but you get my point though

Comment: Why don't you use fgetcsv() in the first place; with the `auto_detect_line_endings` setting as described in the [PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)

Comment: You might like to read this. The `dos2unix` and `unix2dos` utils might be useful as a preprocessor http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613800/how-to-convert-dos-windows-newline-crlf-to-unix-newline-n-in-bash-script Of course @MarkBaker suggestion beats us all into the dust