# Shell Bash Script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I am making a bash script. I have to get 3 variables

```
VAR1=$(cat /path to my file/ | grep "string1" | awk '{ print $2 }'
VAR2=$(cat /path to my file/ | grep "string2" | awk '{ print $2 }'
VAR3=$(cat /path to my file/ | grep "string3" | awk '{ print $4 }'
```

My problem is that if I write

```
echo $VAR1
echo $VAR2
echo $VAR3
```

I can see values correctly

But when I try to write them in one line like this

```
echo "VAR1: $VAR1 VAR2: $VAR2 VAR3: $VAR3"
```

Value from `$VAR3` is written at the beginning of output overwritting values of `$VAR1` and `$VAR2`

I expect my explanation had been clear. Any doubt please let me know

Thanks and regards.

Rambert

Comment: `cat /path to my file/ | grep "string1" | awk '{ print $2 }'` == `awk '/string1/{print $2}' file`. No need for `cat` or `grep` with `awk`.

Comment: @andlrc : echo will not interpret `\r` then without `-e`

Comment: One thing. All variables are strings of numbers.

Answer (score 5):

It seems to me that `$VAR3` contains `\r` which in some shells will move the cursor to the beginning of the line. Use `printf` instead:

```
printf "VAR1: %s VAR2: %s VAR3: %s\n" "$VAR1" "$VAR2" "$VAR3"
```

Also note that the way you extract the values is highly inefficient and can be reduced to one call to `awk`:

```
read -r var1 var2 var3 _ < <(awk '/string1/ { a=$2 }
                                  /string2/ { b=$2 }
                                  /string3/ { c=$4 }
                                        END { print(a, b, c) }' /path/to/file)
printf "VAR1: %s VAR2: %s VAR3: %s\n" "$var1" "$var2" "$var3"
```

A nitpick is that uppercase variable names are reserved for environment variables, so I changed all to lowercase.

`<(...)` is a process substitution and will make `...` write to a "file" and return the file name:

```
$ echo <(ls)
/dev/fd/63
```

And `command < file` is a redirection changing standard input of `command` to be comming from the file `file`.

Comment: Now that I think of it, `read -r a b c <<< "1 2 3"` will not work when one value is missing: `read -r a b c <<< "1  3"` Note that two spaces will be squeezed together and `3` will be stored in `b`. One could however find another delimiter than space and use `IFS` accordingly: `IFS=: read -r a b c <<< "1::3"`. Now `3` will be stored in `c`. (Even SO will squeeze the spaces, but it is: `<<< "1<space><space>3"`)

Comment: You are right. I have edited file with notepad++ and i have seen \r on all lines. So if i convert lines file to Unix everything is OK. I get file from ftp in txt format so i have to convert it and work with it

Comment: @RambertNala There is a million ways to convert line endings :-) See [How to convert DOS/Windows newline (CRLF) to Unix newline (\n) in bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613800/how-to-convert-dos-windows-newline-crlf-to-unix-newline-n-in-bash-script)

Answer (score 1):

You could write :

```
cat /path to my file/ | grep "string1" | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

as

```
awk '/string1/{print $2}' /path/to/file
```

In other words you could do with `awk` alone what you intended to do with `cat, grep & awk`

So finally get :

```
VAR1=$(awk '/string1/{print $2}' /path/to/file) #mind the closing ')'
```

Regarding the issue you face, it looks like you have carriage returns or `\r` in your variables. In bash `echo` will not interpret escape sequences without the `-e` option, but the `printf` option which 
[[ @andlrc ]](https://stackoverflow.com/users/887539/andlrc) pointed out is a good try though as he mentioned in his [[ answer ]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38099128/1620779)

> which in some shells will move the cursor to the beginning

**Notes :**

1. Another subtle point to keep in mind is to avoid using upper case variable names like `VAR1` for user scripts. So replace it with `var1` or so
2. When assigning values to variable spaces are not allowed around `=`, so

   ```
   VAR1="Note there are no spaces around = sign"
   ```

   is the right usage