# property files not in used properly in bash

Tags: bash, shell

Here is my property files

xxx.properties

```
SCRIPT_NAME="AAAAA"
ENVIRON="BBB"
```

Here is my sh file

yyy.sh

```
. xxx.properties
LOG_PREFIX="$SCRIPT_NAME(${ENVIRON})"
echo $SCRIPT_NAME
echo $ENVIRON
echo $LOG_PREFIX
```

If I run yyy.sh, it displays

```
AAAAA
BBB
ABBBA    <--- weird
```

But if I don't use property file and put variables in sh file it works

yyy.sh

```
SCRIPT_NAME="AAAAA"
ENVIRON="BBB"
LOG_PREFIX="$SCRIPT_NAME(${ENVIRON})"
echo $SCRIPT_NAME
echo $ENVIRON
echo $LOG_PREFIX
```

Displays

```
AAAAA
BBB
AAAAA(BBB)   <-- correct
```

why it happens, and how to solve the issue?

Thanks!

Comment: i ran your script on ubuntu, 3.16.0-49-generic #65~14.04.1-Ubuntu, it works as expected

Comment: Can you run `od -c xxx.properties` and show us the results?

Answer (score 2):

If I run your script, I get the desired result:

```
$ bash yyy.sh
AAAAA
BBB
AAAAA(BBB)
```

If I convert xxx.properties to DOS format:

```
$ sed -i 's/$/\r/' xxx.properties
```

And run the script again, I get results that look somewhat similar to yours:

```
$ bash yyy.sh
AAAAA
BBB
)BBBA
```

This is because both `SCRIPT_NAME` and `ENVIRON` now end with a carriage return (`\r`) character.

The solution is to run [`dos2unix` or similar utility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613800/how-to-convert-dos-windows-newline-crlf-to-unix-newline-n-in-bash-script) on xxx.properties to remove DOS line-endings.