# Bash script fails to run node on docker image

Tags: node.js, shell, docker, alpine-linux

I have an app that I want to run on a single self contained Docker image. 
I had it running fine on an [Ubuntu based image](https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu/), but the same script now causes me trouble on [Alpine](https://hub.docker.com/_/alpine/).

Here is my docker file :

```
FROM julienlengrand/alpine-node-rethinkdb

# Preparing
# RUN ln -snf /bin/bash /bin/sh

# # Define mountable directories.
VOLUME ["/data"]

# # Define working directory.
WORKDIR /data

# # Install app dependencies
COPY package.json /data
RUN npm install

# # Bundle app source
COPY . /data

# # Expose rethinkdb ports.
#   - 8080: web UI
#   - 28015: process
#   - 29015: cluster
EXPOSE 8080
#EXPOSE 28015
#EXPOSE 29015

# Expose node app ports
EXPOSE 4567

CMD [ "/bin/sh", "/data/startApp.sh" ]
```

My startApp script is relatively simple :

```
#!/bin/sh
rethinkdb --bind all & sleep 1; node dbCreate.js; sleep 2; nohup node workers/worker.js & node app.js
```

But when I try to run it, I get the following error:

```
module.js:442
    throw err;
    ^

'rror: Cannot find module '/data/app.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:440:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:388:25)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:575:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:352:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:144:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:467:3
```

This happens whether I run it automatically, or directly within the image using the shell.

I have checked and everything is correctly placed in the data folder. 
Additionally, if I run all the commands one after the other directly in the sh shell everything runs as expected.

I have also tried to simplify my script as such :

```
#!/bin/sh
rethinkdb --bind all & sleep 1; node dbCreate.js; sleep 2; node app.js
```

bu the same issue happens.

Any idea what can go wrong? What could make my /data folder unavailable when running via the startApp script? Could it be that it is a specificity from Alpine?

Thanks,

Comment: One suggestion though, do not put everything on a single docker image. think `microservices` - a single docker container should only do one thing. You should have one container for your NodeJS app and another one for RethinkDB. You would use `docker-compose` to easily orchestrate those containers, that is how docker-based apps are supposed to work.

Comment: Hey @HuyGiang. Yes, you are totally right, and that is something we want to do too. Consider this a necessary middle step :).

Comment: I would start with 2 separated container from the beginning, as building the image would be a lot easier, there are official images for both Node and RethinkDB and you can debug your Node container easier without custom startup script.

Comment: I have 2 different node scripts running though, the main app thread and a worker. Does it mean that I should run at least 3 different docker containers?

Comment: It depends on how your app and your worker interact. If they can run independently, you should separate them to their own container.

Comment: Back to your `Dockerfile`, try replacing `VOLUME ["/data"]` with `RUN mkdir /data` and rebuild & run

Comment: @HuyGiang. That is actually exactly what I was trying already :). Doesnt seem to change anything though :S

Comment: it says `Cannot find module '/data/app.js`, so you should check if `app.js` has been copied to `/data` yet. try `docker run -it --rm yourconatiner sh` and `ls /data` to whats inside.

Comment: @HuyGiang. The scripts are in data. I have validated this. If I run directly from within the container everything runs fine. I won't paste the content of my ls here, but all the expected files are there .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you are receiving looks like a classic carriage return issue as the quote after `app.js` has moved to the start of the line

```
'rror: Cannot find module '/data/app.js
```

Node should normally be able to deal with both line endings but shell scripts aren't so kind.

I generally default all projects/files/editors/git to a Unix `\n` unless there are specific requirements not too.

You can convert existing files with `dos2unix` or one of the answers in the [question jlengrand found](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2613800/1318694). I like `perl -pi -e 's/\r\n/\n/g'`, because `pie`

Comment: Indeed.  The problem was coming from a Windows carriage return in my startApp.sh script. I removed it on the host side by using the method described here  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613800/how-to-convert-dos-windows-newline-crlf-to-unix-newline-n-in-bash-script

Comment: Out of interest, are you requiring that file based on the arguments to `node`? I'm trying to figure out how the carriage return got into the module loader.

Comment: No, the only thing I am doing in the script is calling node app.js. I have not touched the node scripts. I was a bit surprised as well that it was enough, tbh and was expecting to have to unixify the node app too.