# How to format bash command lines from separate input lines (from file or stdin)

Tags: bash

I'm trying to put together a script to bulk-update a bunch of database tables. I have a list in a file (but I could just as well have it from stdin), and I'm trying to construct the `ALTER TABLE` commands. I have the following

```
while read table; do echo "ALTER TABLE $table ENGINE=Aria"; done < tables
```

which however outputs something like this

```
 ENGINE=Ariamydatabase.mytableone
 ENGINE=Ariamydatabase.mytabletwo
 ENGINE=Ariamydatabase.mytablethree
```

instead of

```
ALTER TABLE mydatabase.mytableone ENGINE=Aria;
...
```

like I expected. What am I doing wrong? Eventually, I'd change `echo` to `mysql -uroot -ppassword -e"ALTER TABLE $table ENGINE=Aria;"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file `tables` has DOS `\r\n` line endings. This causes `$table` to end with `\r` carriage returns, which when printed move the cursor back to the beginning of the line.

You'll want to [convert `tables` to UNIX `\n` line endings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613800/how-to-convert-dos-windows-newline-crlf-to-unix-newline-n-in-bash-script).

Answer (score -2):

Cat command will handle with your new line saperators.

Try this code:

```
$ cat tables | while read table; do echo "ALTER TABLE $table ENGINE=Aria"; done
```

Comment: `cat file | while` is no different from `while < file`, aside from the [useless use of cat](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html).

Comment: John did you try it?

Comment: Yes. It is no different. cat doesn't translate line endings or strip carriage returns.