# [: missing `]' error with appropriate spacing

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Trying the following:

```
#!sh

#$ -S /bin/bash 

#$ -t 1-8 

if [ ! -e ~/home/output.$SGE_TASK_ID ] 

then ~/fastqc -i ~/home/input.$SGE_TASK_ID -o ~/home/output.$SGE_TASK_ID

fi
```

Getting error:

```
.bash_array: line 7: [: missing `]'
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: what's the value of that variable?

Comment: Does your script have DOS line endings? If so, the last argument on that line is `]\r`, not `]`

Comment: The value of the variable is 1

Comment: quick fix assuming @chepner guessed your problem correctly: try adding semicolons to the ends of your lines.

Comment: @webb That's not a fix, just a way to trigger a different error.

Comment: Yes I get similar errors when doing that.

Comment: aw too bad. then here's how to convert your script's line endings: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613800/how-to-convert-dos-windows-newline-crlf-to-unix-newline-n-in-bash-script (and in future, if you write your scripts in cygwin using eg `nano`, `pico`, `vi`, `vim`, or `emacs` instead of Notepad, this shouldn't be a problem).