# formatting whois results to CSV using BASH and grep

Tags: linux, bash, csv, awk, grep

I've been trying to get my head round this for a few hours now and thought I'd come here and ask for help.

I have a CSV file of IP addresses  from a log file that I want to run through and get a WHOIS netrange and company name from and then append the result to the end of the CSV.

So far what I have managed to do is get the whois results to a separate csv

```
echo ip, company, > result.csv
for ip in $(grep -E -o "([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}" source.csv); do 
    whois $ip | grep -i -e 'netrange\|inetnum' -e 'org-name\|orgname' \
    | awk 'BEGIN{FS="NetRange:|inetnum:|OrgName:|org-name:"} {print $2","$3}'
    |xargs; done >> result.csv
```

my challenge is how to add my 2 new columns back into the source.csv? I have tried using

```
paste -d, source.csv result.csv
```

but all that happens is the values in result.csv overwrite the first few columns of source.csv

my source.csv looks something like the below

```
ip address       requests   number of visits
66.249.90.77      2149      200
66.249.66.1       216       233
```

My result.csv

```
ip range                     company
66.249.64.0 - 66.249.95.255 Google Inc.
66.249.64.0 - 66.249.95.255 Google Inc.
```

i would like my final csv to look like

```
ip            requests  number of visits    ip range               company
66.249.90.77    2149    200           66.249.64.0 - 66.249.95.255   Google Inc.
66.249.66.1      2161   233           66.249.64.0 - 66.249.95.255   Google Inc.
```

If possible I would prefer to accomplish this with BASH rather than installing any 3rd party tools etc. I have tried the python package ipwhois but my python knowledge is far less than my limited BASH knowledge so I abandoned it lest I continue wasting time!

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Do you require that to be a one-liner, or would a loop-based solution work for you?

Comment: `paste` with your example files is working for me (although based on your desired output I don't think you want the `-d,` delimiter).  Is it possible your `source.csv` has DOS line endings? In a Unix environment the extra CR can cause the initial characters in the line to be overwritten by what follows it. Maybe try `cat -v source.csv` and see if any `^M`s appear.

Comment: @Fred any would be fine - thank you.

Comment: @jas you are exactly right! I found extra carriage returns. Is there anyway to fix it? Thank you both

Comment: Yes, lots of ways to fix it. The easiest is if you have a `dos2unix` utility handy. Otherwise, see for example http://stackoverflow.com/a/2613834/2229272

Comment: I double checked when I edited the format of your `for` loop. I don't see what you finish it with `xargs`. Usually `xargs` expects a script/program as an "option" and the list of files coming thru the pipe (`|`), are file arguments to that script/program. Am I missing something (it wouldn't be the first time ;-) ). Good luck.

Comment: If your problem is fixed by removing `^M` chars at line-end, this Q really won't help anyone. Would you please delete it. Good luck.

Comment: @jas thank you so much for helping me. I have fixed the script by using 
sed $'s/\r$//' to convert to Unix format. I have discovered another formatting issue but this is with the way WHOIS record is stored for some IP addresses. I'll raise a new question if I can't sort it myself. Thank you everyone for your help. I can sleep now!!

Comment: You're welcome, glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in a script file and running it while inside the directory containing your data file.

```
#!/bin/bash -ue

# Pattern for spacing characters
sp="[[:space:]]*"

#Pattern for non-spacing characters
nsp="[^[:space:]]+"

# Iterate on each line in the data file
while IFS= read -r line
do
  [[ "$line" =~ ^$sp($nsp)$sp($nsp)$sp($nsp)$sp$ ]] || continue
  f1="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
  f2="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
  f3="${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
  # Extract information from whois
  whois_data="$(whois "$f1")"
  range="$(grep NetRange  <<<"$whois_data" | cut -f2 -d":")"
  company="$(grep OrgName <<<"$whois_data" | cut -f2 -d":")"
  echo $f1,$f2,$f3,$range,$company
done <"source.csv"
```

The output is formatted as fields separated by commas, and there should be some trimming of the `range` and `company` variables before they are used (to remove spaces at the beginning and end), but this should give you the idea.

Basically, the code does not try to merge two files together, but rather extracts the fields from each line of the source file, performs the `whois`, extracts the two fields needed from it, and then outputs all five fields to the output without an intermediary step.