# Add characters at the end of each line

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed

I've tried all solutions that I found, but nothing seems to work as it should.

I have a file with text data. I need to add some characters at the end of each line.

I've tried already:

```
awk '{print $0"XYZ"}' $newfilename-final.txt > $newfilename-XYZ.txt
perl -nle 'print $_, "XYZ"' $newfilename-final.txt > $newfilename-XYZ.txt
sed 's/$/XYZ/' $newfilename-final.txt > $newfilename-XYZ.txt
```

All of them added XYZ, but not at the end of every string, but in new lines between strings.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: you awk solution works here

Comment: and so does your sed one

Comment: You might have a carriage return at the end of the line. `sed -e 's/\r//g' -e 's/$XYZ/g'` could work.

Comment: or add `sub(/\r/,"",$NF)` to the beginning of your awk script to remove the `\r`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing your awk program, it works for me as intended. I suppose the problem is that your input file uses different newline sequences than the your OS default (probably the Windows-style "CR+LF" when you are on UNIX or Mac OS). If that's the case, this other post could be of help: [How to convert DOS/Windows newline (CRLF) to Unix newline (\n) in a Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613800/how-to-convert-dos-windows-newline-crlf-to-unix-newline-n-in-a-bash-script).

Answer (score 0):

if it is every line

```
sed 's/[^[:print:]]*$/[Here]&/' YourFile
```

you take care of every trailing non printable char before the insertion with the `[^[:print:]]*` and  `&` in replacement pattern