# Can't remove line break from $0 in awk

Tags: bash, awk

I'm trying to parse some data from a dat file using awk, however I cant get rid of a linebreak that is being added to `$0`. I've tried `gsub(/\n/,"")`, but it's done nothing.

Example below:

from dat file:

```
<A>1
<B>2
```

running:

```
awk '
BEGIN {FS = ">"; ORS=""; OFS=""}
/<A>/ {printf $2; printf$2}
' file.dat
```

currently gives me:

```
1
1
```

when I want:

```
11
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just want

```
awk -F '>' '/<A>/ { print $2 $2 }' file.dat
```

This being said, your code should work, as well; the problem was that your input file contained DOS style newlines, which can be removed with, for example, `dos2unix`. See [How to convert DOS/Windows newline (CRLF) to Unix newline (\n) in a Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613800/how-to-convert-dos-windows-newline-crlf-to-unix-newline-n-in-a-bash-script) for more ways to do it.

Comment: I've changed the FS and structured the print statement as in your example, but it doesn't do anything about the line break. I still get the same result.

Comment: Actually, your code works for me. Do you have DOS line endings with carriage returns? Does `cat -A file.dat` contain `^M` before the end of each line?

Comment: Yes must be the case. Just now I tested with gsub(/\r/,"") instead and it works. Wasn't aware of carriage returns before. Huge thanks for your help.