# running emconfigure exception with Popen

Tags: python, emscripten

When I run emconfigure ./configure I get the following error:

```
ERROR:root:Exception thrown when invoking Popen in configure with 

args: "./configure"!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/emconfigure", line 13, in <module>
    emconfigure.run()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/emscripten/1.37.21/libexec/emconfigure.py", line 46, in run
    shared.Building.configure(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/emscripten/1.37.21/libexec/tools/shared.py", line 1533, in configure
    process = Popen(args, stdout=None if EM_BUILD_VERBOSE_LEVEL >= 2 else stdout, stderr=None if EM_BUILD_VERBOSE_LEVEL >= 1 else stderr, env=env)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

### Break-down:

This one can be tricky to track down because of the *depth* of the call stack.  Let's break it apart:

At the "next-to-top level": a file you're trying to execute cannot be found.

One level lower than that things become clear: subprocess.Popen is trying to execute args.

What's in args? - basically ./configure (as passed by emscripten).  export the EM_BUILD_VERBOSE=3 environmental variable and then stderr should display this.

So, the next-to-top level ./configure is directing things in an invalid fashion.  Now it's time for a guess *at the top level* (not knowing what's in the ./configure script): is some line of the shell command in the ./configure script file itself trying to execute something non-existent? E.g.: some point after #! /bin/sh ? - try debugging *just* ./compile.

It is worth noting that a subprocess can have issues with relative paths (not getting PATH), and permissions (./configure is locked-down), but your error very well may persist even after /you/make/an/absolute/call/to/configure *and* 777 the permissions of configure. - In that case the previous paragraph is the likeliest culprit.

### Editorializing:

The reason this error is interesting as a general one for emscripten is that part (much) of emscripten's raison d'etre is to port [legacy] C/++ code to new JS apps.  Well, old C/++ builds get old *in the sense of this question*.  If that's true, this is will be a generally-occurring problem, and, if it is general the community could use a general pattern for resolution.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Docker, your host computer is Windows, and you mounted it to a Windows directory, make sure that your files aren't `\r\n` line endings but instead `\n` line endings. Changing this fixed it for me.

In this case, if you're using git, you might try setting `git config core.autocrlf input` to stop checking out to `\r\n`. If you need to convert a file, try [this answer out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2613834/2759427).