# "telnet" command fails with "bad port" when executed in shell script, but works on command prompt

Tags: linux, shell, telnet, putty

This is probably really simple. I am logging into a remote server using PuTTY and running a `telnet 12.34.56.789 22` command to test TCP connections on port 22.

This works fine when I type the command manually, but I have a range of destinations to check and I thought it would be better to use a script for this. I created a very basic shell script which is just a list of the commands I want to run one after another. When I run this script from PuTTY I get an error saying

> : bad port

Can anyone explain to me why the command works when I type it manually, but produces an error when I run the script?

Script:

```
telnet 10.52.33.46 22  
telnet 10.52.33.47 22  
telnet 10.52.33.48 22  
telnet 10.52.33.49 22  
telnet 10.52.33.50 22  
telnet 10.52.33.51 22  
telnet 10.52.33.52 22  
telnet 10.52.33.53 22  
telnet 10.52.33.54 22  
telnet 10.52.33.55 22
```

[Here is a screenshot of the PuTTY window with the error message. I save the above script (159999.sh) onto the host server, then run it from there.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7x9SQ.png)

[Here is some of the commands running after I type them manually (in this case they are supposed to fail to connect)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLFaT.png)

Comment: Could you post your script?

Comment: added to the original question - added a few line spaces for readability

Comment: *"When I run **these**"* - Do you mean *"When I run **this script**"*? How do you run the script (if you do)? Show us a screenshot.

Comment: 22 is a port of SSH service. It might be that telnet client on your server doesn’t allow port alterations.

Comment: OK, show us screenshot running the commands manually. Also can you upload the script somewhere (zipped) for us to check?

Comment: struggling to upload the script, but it is essentially the commands in the question, typed on individual lines (without line spaces) in a .sh file and saved on the host server

Comment: Did you save that file in windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script file has Windows CR/LF line endings, while *nix systems use LF only.

The additional CR is taken as a part of the `telnet` command, particularly as a part of the last "port" argument. Hence the *"bad port"* error.

Make sure you either:

- save the script using *nix line endings before uploading or
- upload the script using a text mode transfer or
- [convert the file on the server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2613800/850848).