# printing the column multiple times with awk

Tags: linux, awk

I have a tab separated file, that has 5 columns:

```
file1.txt
1   101 T   A   0.36
1   101 T   C   0.43
1   101 T   G   0.28
1   102 A   C   0.36
```

I want to print the last column twice so I want to have:

```
1   101 T   A   0.36 0.36
1   101 T   C   0.43 0.43
1   101 T   G   0.28 0.28
1   102 A   C   0.36 0.36
```

And I try:

```
cat file1.txt | awk -v OFS="\t" '$1=$1'| awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$5}'
```

which outputs only the last column as :

```
0.36
0.43
0.28
0.36
```

I have also tried:

```
awk '{print $0,$5}' file1.txt
```

Which printed the same :
which outputs only the last column as :

```
0.36
0.43
0.28
0.36
```

When I have `cut` command,I can separately print out `cut -f1` and `cut -f2` and so on, so there is no problem with that.

I couldnt understand what is going on and wanted to ask that how can I print the last column twice?

Comment: Why do you need the first `awk` command in the pipeline?

Comment: @Barmar as a caution I wanted to change the delimitation to tabs

Comment: Your first command line works fine for me. I'll bet your file has CRLF line breaks, use `dos2unix` to convert them.

Comment: @Barmar what is that? can you expand please?

Comment: @bapors see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations_in_different_character_encoding_specifications ... you can check it by using `cat -e file1.txt` .. if you see `^M$` at end of line, you have dos style line ending

Comment: @bapors See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613800/how-to-convert-dos-windows-newline-crlf-to-unix-newline-n-in-a-bash-script/2613834#2613834

Comment: Just a general comment : tabs are evil!

Comment: @Sundeep yes.. it has all '^M$'s

Comment: You can try: awk 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"}{print $0,$NF}' file

Answer (score 2):

To print the *last field twice*:

```
awk '{ $NF=$NF OFS $NF }1' OFS='\t' file
```

The output:

```
1   101 T   A   0.36    0.36
1   101 T   C   0.43    0.43
1   101 T   G   0.28    0.28
1   102 A   C   0.36    0.36
```

Comment: No.. still it prints the $1,$5, $5