# sed/bash move digits from end of line to front of line

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Okay so I want to move all digits from end of the line to the front of the line, example of lines:

```
example123
example321
example2920
```

expected output:

```
123example
321example
2920example
```

the following sed command works to place numbers at the start to end -

```
sed -E 's/^([0-9]+)(.*)/\2\1/' file
```

input of this is

```
123example
321example
```

and output is

```
example123
example321
```

but when trying to do the same for numbers at the end moved to the front I can't seem to do it..

I've tried changing

```
^
```

to

```
$
```

and other things but I'm new to sed so I don't really understand alot.

Comment: This looks exactly same post as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49335245/awk-bash-move-digits-from-front-of-line-to-end-of-line please refrain posting samething.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The working example you give matches "a string of digits followed by anything". You might think that you could alter it to match "anything followed by some digits" (`/\(.*\)\([0-9]*\)`/), but the trouble is that sed matches as much as it can; in the working example it grabs as many digits as it can, and in the naive new version it grabs everything in the first term.

The trick is to match *non-digits followed by anything*:

```
sed 's/\([^0-9]*\)\(.*\)/\2\1/' filename
```

**EDIT:** I hadn't thought of the possibility of *non*-trailing digits. This:

```
sed 's/\(.*[^0-9]\)\(.*\)/\2\1/' filename
```

will turn

```
Ex1am2ple123
```

to

```
123Ex1am2ple
```

Comment: Problem with that is, if a line contains "Ex1am2ple123" I only want the ending digits to the front of the line, so in this example output would be 123Ex1am2ple

Comment: @NoobLearning: I hadn't thought of that. I'll edit. (And yes, it informs me of all comments on my Answer.)

Comment: @Beta Try: `sed 's/\(.*[^[:digit:]]\)\([[:digit:]]*$\)/\2\1/'`

Comment: @John1024: Thanks, but my solution is a little simpler.

Comment: Thank you @John1024 & Beta both solutions work, I have accepted your answer Beta, really appreciate the help :)!

Comment: Btw, in order to be similar to the command style provided in the question (extended regexp) the answer can be rewritten as sed -E 's/(.*[^0-9])(.*)/\2\1/' file

Comment: @SergeySargsyan: Good point.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk, you could match the trailing digits, and then print that, and a substring of the input, chopping off at the end the number of characters that were matched:

```
awk 'match($0, /[0-9]+$/, m) {print m[0] substr($0, 0, length($0) - length(m[0]))}' file
```

This solution works even if there are digits in the prefix, for example:

```
$ cat file
ex456le123
456mple321
example2920
$ gawk 'match($0, /[0-9]+$/, m) {print m[0] substr($0, 0, length($0) - length(m[0]))}' file
123ex456le
321456mple
2920example
```

Comment: @jonas your answer worked as well as Beta's but I accepted his due to it being sed within the total, but I've +1'd your comment as it does work, so thank you for your help :)

Comment: Any idea why this: `awk -F'[0-9]' '{print substr($0,length($1)+1) $1}'  file`  will need a `length($1)+1` ?