# Why is there a trailing '?' at the end of my directory in Unix?

Tags: unix

I am creating a directory using the following command in Unix. This line is a part of a shell script which I am trying to run.

```
mkdir ./R
```

And it makes a dir named `R?`
What does this mean?

Comment: What leads you to believe that's the directory it's created? Does `stat R?` succeed yet `stat R` does not?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using `ls` to see this `?` symbol, [`man ls`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ls) notes that the `--hide-control-chars` will insert `?` symbols where a filename has non-graphic characters. Assuming this flag is set (e.g. if you have an alias `alias ls=ls -q`) It's possible your `mkdir` command has an additional non-printing character after the `R` (e.g. if you copy-pasted the line from somewhere).

Comment: Some versions of `ls` behave this way by default. `man ls` to find options to change the way file names are displayed. Or use filename completion to change the name: `mv R<tab> R` (if the directory is the only thing in the current directory whose name starts with `R`, this will let you rename it -- and what the tab expansion shows could be informative). Your answer assumes the GNU coreutils version of `ls`; since the OP only said Unix, that's not a safe assumption.

Answer (score 1):

Your shell script has DOS line endings. The shell sees the command as `mkdir ./R^M` where `^M` is a carriage return. You can confirm this with `cat -v`.

```
$ cat -v script
mkdir ./R^M
```

`ls` will print control characters with question marks `?`. Printing them directly would mess up its output.

To fix the file [convert it from DOS to UNIX format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613800/how-to-convert-dos-windows-newline-crlf-to-unix-newline-lf-in-a-bash-script).