# Windows 10 Docker : /usr/bin/env: 'php\r': No such file or directory

Tags: php, windows, docker, docker-compose, docker-for-windows

I have a docker-compose.yml file where i defined the images and the build for php. Its made for a Symfony application with php, nginx and postgresql with postgis:

```
version: '2'
services: 

 front:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - "81:80"
    links:
      - "engine:engine"
      - "db:db"
    volumes:
      - ".:/home/docker:ro"
      - "./docker/front/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro"

 engine:
    build: ./docker/engine/
    volumes:
      - ".:/home/docker:rw"
      - "./docker/engine/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/custom.ini:ro"
    links:
      - "db:db"
    working_dir: "/home/docker"



  db:
    image: camptocamp/postgres:9.6
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
    environment:
      - "POSTGRES_DB=pfe"
      - "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin"
      - "POSTGRES_USER=admin"
      - "PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata"
```

Everything works fine on Ubuntu but when i tryied to run the same environement onw windows 10 i got an error.

```
docker-compose exec engine bin/console doctrine:schema:create
    /usr/bin/env: 'php\r': No such file or directory
```

Comment: maybe the php command is not defined in your windows environment variables

Comment: Did you have a solution?

Answer (score 24):

I figure out a way to solve based on this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2613834/3257568

```
tr -d '\015' <DOS-file >UNIX-file
```

So, I did this:

```
$ docker exec -it <container> bash
$ cd bin
$ tr -d '\015' <console >console.new
$ mv console console.old
$ mv console.new console
```

It's now working :)

Answer (score 12):

From the error message it seems you are facing issue related to EOL.

Try converting your scripts/files to UNIX formatted EOL.

You can use Sublime / Notepadd++ or any editor that supports this feature.
Or on unix platform you can try [dos2unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613800/how-to-convert-dos-windows-newline-crlf-to-unix-newline-lf-in-a-bash-script).

Comment: They are formated as for Unix! But the issue that Docker can't make the php run in the container. It works for postgresql when i use: docker-compose exec db psql *database name* -U *database user name*

Comment: And as the built was made with docker on windows that runs on Linux containers in Hyper-V! omg this is really complicated

Comment: Do login into the container and execute the command inside container manually.

Comment: `docker-compose exec -it engine sh`  and then inside console try `bin/console doctrine:schema:create`

Comment: Sorry but it doesnt work! it just shows me the help as the command is wrong

Comment: try `docker-compose exec engine sh` -- Did you get a console

Comment: This is what i get : ERROR: Windows named pipe error: Le fichier spécifié est introuvable. (code: 2)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173139/discussion-between-fly2matrix-and-salim-ben-aissa).

Answer (score 6):

1. Another possible fix for this kind of error is to add .gitattribues file to your project and set `*.sh   text eol=lf` (on any file extension that is run inside your docker containers). This way git defaults on Windows won't mess your .sh files. Caution: you need to get fresh git pull for this to work.
2. In my case the error was just running php script that did not have right permissions. So you chmod it beforehand or add `php` at the beginning. Ex: `php bin/console`

Both problems could lead to the same error.

Comment: makes me angry that this is even necessary. Windows has no problem using unix line endings, nobody cares, and it only breaks things if you don't use them. Drives me nuts.

Answer (score 1):

In my case removing the `chmod +x` conversion and instead adding `php` to the beginning of the command that produces the error

Comment: I don't see any `chmod +x` in the question, thus this does not provide an answer to it. If you are referring to another answer, please indicate which one, otherwise it is better to explain the steps you have followed to answer the question on your side

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`tr -d '\15' < original_file > converted_file`

In your case:

`tr -d '\15' < bin/console > console`

And next replace this file(move the file console to directory bin)

For me working :-)

Comment: Also don't forget to make file executable with: chmod +x bin/console