# Ansible Playbook keeps adding ^M to my files

Tags: ansible, character

I have the below ansible playbook where i am identifying a string in a file and replacing it with another

```
---
- name: Ansible Playbook
  hosts: webserver1
  remote_user: user45

  tasks:
  - name: Replacing content with other
    lineinfile:
     path: /home/user45/run.sh
     regexp: '^(.*)DEBUG=(.*)$'
     line: 'DEBUG=ON'
```

the above works, but it adds ^M to the end of every other line in that file and every blank line

From what I have read online this normally occurs when you copy and paste from Windows to Linux but i typed this out manually so i am kind of stumped

Playbook is running on Linux Redhat 7

Comment: On which os you are running playbook?

Comment: Playbook is running on Linux Redhat 7

Comment: I have a suspicion that `run.sh` already has Windows-style line-endings (i.e. it already has carriage return `^M` characters). You can check this using `od -c /home/user45/run.sh` command. `^M` characters will be displayed as `\r`.

Comment: You are correct .. I see /r all over the output

Answer (score 0):

Please verify your script "/home/user45/run.sh".Looks like carriage-return character exist in there.

Comment: Confirmed, carriage-return character does not exist in the run.sh prior to ansible touching

Comment: Whats your ansible verison? let us know the host server where you are running and the remote server (webserver1) OS details. Also if possible please post verbose output to dig further.

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason lineinfile was adding the ^M .. If I change it to use replace module it does not add the ^M bits

```
---
- name: Ansible Playbook
  hosts: webserver1
  remote_user: user45

  tasks:
  - name: Replacing content with other
    replace:
     dest: /home/user45/run.sh
     regexp: 'DEBUG=.*'
     line: 'DEBUG=ON'
```

Answer (score 0):

It works on ansible 2.9:

```
---
- name: Ansible Playbook
  hosts: webserver1
  remote_user: user45

  tasks:
  - name: Replacing content with other
    replace:
     path: /home/user45/run.sh
     regexp: 'DEBUG=.*'
     replace: 'DEBUG=ON'
```

Enjoy ;)

Answer (score 0):

The issue you were running into is that your config file has windows style CRLF line breaks but ansible inserts LF line breaks. If your file has only CRLF line breaks most text editors will hide the line endings, but if there's a mix of LF and CRLF line endings your editor will show `^M` for every CR. Ansible isn't inserting a bunch of `^M` characters. It's removing a single `^M` character which is changing your editor's behavior.

The simplest fix here (since you're in Linux) is to [replace the CRLF line endings with LFs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613800/how-to-convert-dos-windows-newline-crlf-to-unix-newline-lf).

If for some reason you can't do that (maybe the config file gets overwritten regularly by code you don't control), then, as you discovered, `replace` will work because it doesn't touch the line endings. `replace` and `lineinefile` have different semantics though. Importantly, `replace` won't add a line if there's no matching line already. You can still use `lineinfile` if you add back in the CR:

```
---
- name: Ansible Playbook
  hosts: webserver1
  remote_user: user45

  tasks:
  - name: Replacing content with other
    lineinfile:
     path: /home/user45/run.sh
     regexp: '^(.*)DEBUG='
     line: "DEBUG=ON\r"
```

With the CR (`\r`) at the end of the line, and the LF that ansible inserts automatically, the line will now be CRLF terminated consistent with the rest of your file. Note the double-quotes on line - that's necessary for yaml to process the CR escape sequence.