# Why two file with same text and encoding but have different size?

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, hex, newline, eol

I run a program with two 'same' test files separately but got two different results.

First test file `a.txt` of 16 bytes leads to a right result, but second test file `b.txt` of 14 bytes causes the wrong result.

I saved both of them in encoding `UTF-8`.

Both of them consist of the following three lines when opened with Sublime Text in encoding `UTF-8`:

```
p cnf 1 1
1 0
```

However, they are different when opened with Sublime Text in encoding Hexadecimal:

`a.txt` (16 bytes):

```
7020 636e 6620 3120 310d 0a31 2030 0d0a
```

`b.txt` (14 bytes):

```
7020 636e 6620 3120 310a 3120 300a
```

Why they are different? How can I turn `b.txt` to `a.txt`?

Comment: Note: some editors cleanup the file. Unicode text could have unnecessary code points (especially if input were a keyboard), and there are also different normalizations. In your case the accepted solution is the real reason, but you may encounter other cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first file has windows style end of line markers: a carriage return followed by a newline `'\r\n'`, hex `0d 0a`.

The second has unix style: a newline `'\n'` hex `0a`.

There are many ways to convert from one style to the other.  Sublime text may have an option to save with particular line endings, find/replace may work, or if you are on a Unix-like system you may try the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613800/how-to-convert-dos-windows-newline-crlf-to-unix-newline-lf-in-a-bash-script).