# Issue in reading data from CSV file in bash script

Tags: bash

I am writing a bash script which will read a CSV file and print the result in console with some string concatenation.

I am facing one issue with one string overwriting part of another when concatenating them in a bash script. Below is the whole code given and I am running it in Gitbash installed on my windows.

**CSV File1 with two rows is given below**

```
Apple,Cycle
Orange,Lamborgini
```

**Script:**

```
while IFS=, read -r x y
    do
            fruit=$x
            vehicle=$y
            echo "$y ran"
done < File1.csv
```

**Actual Output:**

```
ranle
ranborgini
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Cycle ran
Lamborgini ran
```

Comment: It works fine. There's no issue with that script and it gives the expected output. Maybe try to `set -x` and see what is happening for you?

Comment: Works on my machine. I think it's the csv file you are using (it looks like a '\r' issue).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that the output contains carriage return that needs to be removed. For the example above this could be done using the tr tool:

```
 while IFS=, read -r x y                                                                                          
 do
            fruit=$x
            vehicle=$(echo "$y" | tr -d '\r')
            echo "$y ran"
done < File1.csv
```

And now it is giving the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows file probably contains ***CLRF windows new lines with carriage return***, not Unix ones.

Check [this SO question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2613800/12520350) on options for converting new lines in file / line / string.